# Flagging migration should include more options

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, migration

I have encountered numerous questions in with the sprite-kit tag such as:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215645/should-i-use-sprite-kit-for-a-simple-game-like-flappy-bird-or-games-that-simpler

These questions do not belong on SO, but when I flag them and choose Other Reason -> Off-topic -> Other site, it shows only a limited number of options, like SuperUser, ServerFault, etc

The above question would fit in this site: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration

Comment: Thanks, but considering the question was asked all the way back in 2011, has anything been done about this?

Comment: See the "linked" section on that question, the issue comes up extremely regularly, and regularly the same answers are given.

Comment: I was looking for this question in the context of Triage reviews.

Comment: I had a similar question to ask, will it not be appropriate to include the tags of the question as one of the criteria  to list related community sites while flagging questions for migration?

Comment: This still irritates me. Doesnt the migration happen after X amount of votes? If so, what is the problem with adding all SE sites to the list? Nothing gets migrated unless X users vote so. If off-topic stuff get's through that, then just x+=10.

Comment: The list of sites on the “This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network” borders on useless. Seriously, just let us pick the site from a search list of all the sites. A human can probably pick the appropriate destination far better than a static list of five sites. Or if StackOverflow really is going to limit us to a short list of sites, it should suggest ones based upon the tags in the question (suggest sites that have the greatest overlap of tags as those present in the existing question).

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The off-topic migration targets are based on migration statistics; both the number of migrations and the success rate of those migrations.

There were only 4 migrations to Gamedev in the past 90 days, one of which was rejected, vs 307 to DBA and 178 to Super User. It doesn't even feature in the top 10 of migration targets. As such it is not likely it'll be added to the migration targets list any time soon.

There is another problem here however. Most of such questions are *not actually off-topic on Stack Overflow*. Sure, they may be on-topic on Game Dev *as well* but that is no reason to migrate a question. Only *off-topic* but otherwise high quality questions should be migrated; you can flag such a post with the 'other' option and an explanation why the post should be migrated; a moderator will handle the migration in that case.

Just leave a friendly comment informing the user of the existence of GameDev and how they could get great answers to their questions there.

The problem with allowing arbitrary sites to be entered is that a lot of the time, the community on one site has *really no idea* what is on-topic and considered of sufficient quality on another site. As such the Stack Exchange dev team has resisted adding a open-ended migrate option; the Stack Overflow community doesn't get to decide what is on topic in other communities, basically.

Comment: I have done this before, and will do so again. But, how should such a question be flagged (i.e. what category should it be flagged under)?

Comment: @akashg: *if* the question is off-topic but of high quality, use the 'other' option and explain to a moderator that you want the post to be migrated to GameDev.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i was just about to post this as a feature request. I hope you saw the other answer... regarding the *other* option.... leaving friendly comments is what i'm doing currently, but it's a bit waste of time while i'm trying to do my part dealing with the 12k close vote queue...

Comment: @TilwinJoy: I addressed that 'other' option idea now; it has been rejected in the past, for very specific reasons.

Comment: *`off-topic migration targets are based on migration statistics'* -  If a site isn't listed in the off-topic list, then I would say it has significantly less chance of being migrated to; for example, I suspect questions which are probably best fitted for unix.stachexchange or askubuntu are now often tagged as superuser, because unix & askubuntu aren't listed...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: you can still use the `other` option to suggest migrating to those sites; it will just not be automatic on a majority vote. In the past 90 days, U&L received 18 questions from us (1 rejected), Ask Ubuntu got 17 (3 rejected). Now, if *SuperUser* moderators have a problem with U&L / Ubuntu migrations coming their way, perhaps something can be adjusted, but so far they've only rejected 10 out of 107 migrations these past 3 months.

Comment: Your fourth paragraph would encourage the poster to cross-post.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: that comment should include that deleting in one place and posting in the other is the right course of action.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `the community on one site has really no idea what is on-topic and considered of sufficient quality on another site` - Isn't this justification against migration altogether, not just against adding options?

Comment: @BroSlow: for some sites the migrations are reasonably successful because people appear to get confused often enough to post them on Stack Overflow instead and the quality of such topics isn't (usually) low. Those are the topics that get a place in the list.

Comment: @BroSlow: one of those is code reviews (how can I improve this working piece of code). Now that CodeReview.SE is graduated I expect to see a migration option for that site to appear soon.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Would it not be a viable option that if the flagging user is already a member on another stackexchange site with a certain standing, that they can target a question for migration to that site? i.e. often there are process/pattern questions posted on stackoverflow which are better suited to programmers.SE. I am a member of both sites and would like to migrate questions because I do know what is required on each site.

Comment: @toadflakz: most posts I see on Stack Overflow that are actually off-topic, are not suitable for Programmers either. Migration should be used only for *quality* questions. Programmers has a pretty high bar to clear when it comes to that criteria. You may be a member of Programmers, but I see you don't have all that much experience there yet (2 months, 1 question, one answer). I'd sit out your time with Programmers a little longer before you start nominating anything for migration.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You've missed my point tho' - would it not be viable that members of two sites on StackExchange (with a certain standing on both sites) would be allowed to make the call to migrate? As they have a certain level of trust on both sites it would suggest that the call to migrate by that user is a good one.

Comment: @toadflakz: I did get your point and I am pointing out that even members of both sites sometimes don't know what should be migrated. So you need to put on minimum reputation requirements. And then you find out that the number of people that have sufficient reputation on both sites to both vote to close and reopen (a reasonable minimum) are actually *quite rare*; there are not enough around to gain consensus on such posts. Putting the onus on the moderators (the status quo) and not put in dev effort is just fine.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was helpful. But one word one the friendly comment thing: at the moment I do this this way "`This question better suites / belogs to the <other site as a link>`". And during reviews this is quite expensive work typing this every time, switching to another tab to lookup the URL and creating a link, finally flagging as blatanly offtopic. I also sencond gparyani's comment.

Comment: About "The problem with allowing arbitrary sites to be entered is that a lot of the time, the community on one site has really no idea what is on-topic and considered of sufficient quality on another site. " why not using the list of current communities in which the reviewer has an account? Even with some minimum limit of reputation. That way you can hope the reviewer has knowledge of the target site topic.

Comment: As such the Stack Exchange dev team has resisted adding a open-ended migrate option; the Stack Overflow community doesn't get to decide what is on topic in other communities - If they don't thrust the community for doing it, then what is the whole point of SO ??? I don't agree with this and surely would prefer to be able to flag the question correctly instead of using these suggested "workarounds".

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp: what has this got to do with the point of SO? The point of SO is not that the community here gets to decide what is on-topic and appropriate for other communities. That's the point of those *other sites*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: And what is the problem migrating a questions to another website? If the question is off-topic there, it should also be closed or re-migrated. If it came from SO, then one should not be able to migrate it back, to avoid a ping-pong effect. My point is, let people decide how to organize the questions, there are a lot of experts out there capable of doing it. Blocking them makes everything worse, I see many good questions in SO which remain unanswered simply because they are off-topic, and could have been answered if they were migrated to the right place.

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp: so you think it is better to just bounce someone around and give them an even worse experience, and to give the other community some extra work-out dealing with our crap?

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp: There may be experts here, but there are more people that are **not experts at other sites** than there are people that actually know what another site is about. The result is that loads of posts that are just off topic both here and there get migrated anyway, or worse, posts that are actually on topic here too get misinterpreted as 'being about X, so lets move it to X.SE'. A lot of people great at answering computer programming problems, have a blind spot about this. Question involving VI? Migrate it, there's a site for it! Android? Migrate it, there's a site for it!...,

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp: so yes, there are a lot of problems with just letting everyone vote to migrate to other sites. This was a huge problem for programming.SE (now rebranded to Software Engineering), and Server Fault quickly closed the doors when they were on the migration path because a lot of bad posts were being sent over. Code Review [wrote a dedicated post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1687), to try to educate the huge number of people commenting on SO posts to say that 'Code Review is a better place for this' but failed to check if the code actually works, etc.

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp: see [Please stop using SoftwareEngineering.SE as your toilet bowl](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382) for the Programming.SE side of the story.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought the whole point of requiring multiple votes to close a question was so a consensus could be reached. If I see a question in Russian, I want to recommend https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ and it should be accepted once 3 people agree.

Comment: @Marquizzo Statistics show that even requiring multiple people to agree, the rejection rate of migrated questions is too high. This is often because a significant portion of these votes are made from users who have little experience with the target site. Moreover, the problem with migrating questions to SO in other languages is also because most of those often have other issues, and would just be closed even if translated to English.

Comment: @Marquizzo: *closing* is not the same thing as *migrating*. Close voting works because a large enough percentage of users with closing privileges know how *this* site works and what is and what is not on topic. The same can't be said for knowing what is on topic for *another site*; voting to *migrate* posts only works if most users *here* know what is on topic *there*. This is why the list of sites you can vote to migrate to is strictly limited, to a subset where a) we have a larger number of posts that require migrations and so the community can help and b) we don't migrate too much crap.

Comment: This problem is *my* biggest peve with SO. Why not include all sites on the screen? And make the migration only happen if X number of votes to migrate to said site happen.  That way it is the community that decides.

Comment: "There were only 4 migrations to Gamedev in the past 90 days, one of which was rejected, vs 307 to DBA and 178 to Super User. It doesn't even feature in the top 10 of migration targets. As such it is not likely it'll be added to the migration targets list any time soon." The reason DBA and Super User have so many more migrations is **because** they're listed in the flag options. It is completely non-obvious (at least to me) that the correct flag is "In need of moderator intervention" rather than "Not about programming or software development" or "A community-specific reason > Other".

Answer (score 151):

Please add an open option ("Other" ___________ ) to allow people to enter another stackexchange site.

The Off-Topic options include

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

and if this is an appropriate choice, then the following dialog box should always allow the right site to be entered.

Comment: Also see [Better "Flag for migration" interface](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210545)

Comment: Related: [Propose Close -> Migration options based on tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265535/589259)

Comment: I read everything here and agree with @JasonS. I'm going to flag off-topic questions that I cannot vote to migrate to the correct community.

Comment: I agree as well. I feel like people who should have been flagging migration to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead just marked it as off-topic, and thus the poster has no idea where the RIGHT place to post it is.

Comment: I think that with a growing number of "specialized" StackExchange sites (such as "game development" but also "quantum computing") such an option definitely will become necessary.

Answer (score 40):

I can see the point made by Martijin "the Stack Overflow community doesn't get to decide what is on topic in other communities." But there are users that know other communities, so what about allowing suggesting migrations to "others" if the user has more than, say, 1k reputation in the *destination* site? That user will certainly know if the question meets the quality requirements.

Should I put this in a new question?

Comment: Yes, make this a new discussion.

Comment: and when you do... link to it here? :)

Comment: Where is your new question for me to upvote it!

Comment: Is this still not a thing?

Answer (score 8):

I see lots of questions at the [embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded) tag that would be a good match for electronics.stackexchange. Maybe migration options can be tied to the tags used in the questions to ensure only good migration option are presented.

Answer (score 7):

I was going to raise a new question but instead first searched (who does that?) and found this (one of many related) post on the matter. This is in response to [@Martijn-Pieters answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251654/598141) and the comments in the thread, including [@mxmissile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options#comment778007_251654), as much as my question.

> Have you ever walked through a campus, park or large grassy area and noticed even though there's a perfectly good paved pathway "over there", most people seem to walk on the the muddy path that's been created "over here". If you are the maintainer of that space, what are you going to do about it?
>
> Rephrase to, 'why do people keep asking questions "over here", when there's a perfectly good SE site "over there"?' It seems the most popular response from the SE/SO community is, "People should know to use the path", shouting others are wrong for using the mud path, occasionally pointing out (sometimes with kindness), are they aware there's a non-muddy path "over there" and rarely, using their magical/modder powers to teleport them onto the right path.
>
> Maybe simply putting up a sign indicating please use the path, erecting one of those tiny little barriers (say plantings or a [little  fence](https://www.plantsupportsupplier.com/img/garden-border-fence-picture.jpg)) to encourage them to use the path, or maybe simply realigning the path with the most travelled route are options to consider?

My *biggest peve* with SE is decisions seem to made by SE Devs (or Mods) based on the implied knowledge of the user community and not by understanding the community. How many first-time posters ever read the FAQ, much less visit Meta, or read the 1000's of posts here (and meta.se) providing often conflicting guidance? They do what they do, not what you expect of them.

Trying to be helpful, if I recognize a Q is best answered in another site and choose Close | Belongs on another site, then the site is not listed is the choices, I am given no guidance as to what to do.

Instead, I just don't vote to close or flag and leave it to stagnate here (or accumulate downvotes), frustrating the OP who has no idea why they get no responses except downvotes. That's already 2 bad user experiences. I could choose to close with another option of even Flag for Mod, but those might not be any more appropriate or accurate, another bad experience for others.

Any migration stats are skewed and implicitly biased on many levels as they only measure a portion of potential migrations.

**Proposal:**

If migrations are automatic once sufficient votes are registered for the same action, then add an option "Other _____" and create similar workflow ...

If a target site is not listed, a flagger may enter ANY other site they believe is suitable (perhaps even with suggestions based on common tags rather than just personal knowledge). The question is then sent to a moderation queue for review. If the reviewers accept the vote, it is manually migrated. Only once a minimum number of successful migrations and a minimum success rate achieved is it added to an eligible target list. The different site list would only ever show the most popular sites approved migration sites anyway.

Similarly if proposed moves to a site are rejected, then the Vote to move could alert the flagger "most votes to move to X are rejected. Are you sure?", and if the flagger proceeds, it goes to the review queue.

---

**More fundamentally**, someone needs to get to the underlying cause of why are so many people not posting questions to the most appropriate site (that's semantically different to the wrong site) to begin with? Is this a case of users not knowing of the existence of other sites, being directed to post questions here, or seeing so many similar/ related questions on this site that were not migrated to a more suitable site they just figure this is where they will be answered?

Take for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71448781/what-are-the-steps-in-devops-for-a-database-app). Maybe this is best answered is DevOps, or maybe DBA, SW-Eng, or SQA/Test; IDK? I'm not a member of all those sites, I just feel SO is not the best place to get an answer for it.

It was only recently that DevOps site came out of beta, probably spun off from the many Q asked in S/O (and maybe SW-Eng, SuperUser and others) on the topic. If DevOps related questions were previously answered on S/O, then there's still a large body of DevOps questions and answers here, much larger than in DevOps.

If you want to encourage questions to be asked on the correct site, those legacy Questions/Answers should be migrated there. Instead users, especially new users will go with what they see, perpetuating poor choices, making work for mods and diminishing the experience and effectiveness of SE/SO for all.

Sadly, pointing out these observations in meta.so often seems to get the response equivalent of "get off my lawn", or "I told the other person to get off my lawn yesterday, why didn't you listen?". By now if I even notice, my reaction is just a though to myself, "Oh look, another person on the mud path", and I carry on.

Answer (score -4):

There are a lot of Data Security questions which should be transferred to Information Security SE or Cryptography SE because these SE's have a higher standard of user knowldge, giving better information, whereas Data Security responses on SO seem far less knowledgeable.

Comment: did you ask at Security and Cryptography meta whether they want that?

Answer (score -5):

I have recently seen quite a number of questions with the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/obd-ii tag that are more on-topic on the 'mechanics' site. Please consider adding this option.

Comment: did you ask at mechanics meta whether they want that?

Comment: Please consider reading the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: I did, thanks for the note. By that logic though you would need to forbid _all_ entries in the flagging dialog.

Comment: @gnat Not yet, would that make a difference now that the "powers" seem to have decided?

Comment: @DrMickeyLauer if they were enthusiastically in favor of that, I would expect that could make much difference

Comment: @gnat Ok, let me do that and come back with an answer.

Comment: Please come back with a new question. Answers are not the correct place for requests.

Comment: @HereticMonkey By answer I meant the answer from the Mechanics folks…