# Add the option to migrate to programmers on the flag

Tags: feature-request

This is related to this question "[Flagging migration should include more options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options)". But more specific and I believe it is more valid then the suggestion he made there.

This is a site about programming and as such, I believe it's more likely to someone confuse and post the question here instead (or don't know about programmers).

**Example**

This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250578/swing-component-name-suggestion-for-a-specific-interface is too broad for posting here. But it is also a valid question on Programmers and I commented that it should be posted there.

I flagged it for the moderator with the following sentence:

> This question is more suitable to programmers.stackexchange.com (it's about a concept)

And the flag wasn't considered helpful, I usually do not care if my flag is considered unhelpful and I agree that I might have some moderators time flagging such, but since it is not possible to flag to migrate to programmers in another way I thought it was the right way to do it.

But that wouldn't have happened if there was this option.

Comment: [MSE: Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)

Comment: So the fact that you tried to get a moderator to migrate a question for you, **and you were told that it shouldn't be migrated, because it doesn't belong on programmers** your response is to be able to migrate the post without moderator intervention?  Um...no.  The fact that you're trying to migrate questions like these to programmers is **exactly why programmers isn't a valid migration option**.  Note that, as a result of you telling this user to post on programmers they did, and their question [was closed there](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/245312/55447).

Comment: see: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No we won't consider this.

There was a migration route from Stack Overflow to Programmers, but it led to this:

> [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)

We don't want a repeat of that.

The vast majority of questions we see flagged for migration (not just to Programmers, but to any site not on the dialog) are just poor questions and should be closed as such on the site not migrated away.

The question you link to is a prime example of that. It's a "name my class" question. How is that useful to anyone? Therefore your flag was **not** helpful and was correctly declined.

Comment: Then why are there two sites with mutually exclusive topics?   This seems like "we made sites and rules for the sites but we we expect people to enforce the rules but we don't trust them to enforce the rules so while we give them tools to enforce the rules, we neuter the tools so they can't"  Seriously, WTF?  Maybe someone needs to go back to the beginning and really think about the core concepts involved if the system is unmaintainable without resorting to removing the core functionality that people are supposed to use.

Comment: So now, instead of questions that should be migrated to "programmers" get closed and dropped on the floor at SO.  Great job boys.  Some sort of moderation queue for moving the question might be a better solution than "we know you want this feature, but we don't trust you with it".

Comment: And regardless of all this, the only reason this is a problem is because no one has heard of "programmers" and just posts everything to SE.  If they had equal knowledge of both, all these garbage questions that were supposedly being dumped on "programmers" via migration would have gone there in the first place, anyhow, so I don't see why it's actually a problem.