# Similar to "Linked" section but "Linkers"

Tags: discussion, linked-questions

The side bar of the question page currently has a "Linked" section.

[image]

Would it be possible to add the inverse of this section to the sidebar as well that you show a list of the questions that are currently linked to this question?

The reason I feel this would be useful is it would help with searching.  If I am looking at a specific question that I have in my favorites in which I know the answers to bne outdated, it would be helpful to find a list of questions that are linked to this one so I might be a ble to find questions with newer answers.

Comment: Please consider rewriting the question.

Comment: Just saw the comments on this topic. I'll reword it right away. (haha thx for spending time to understand it @psubsee2003 thx for that recommendation)

Comment: @Noitidart I revised your edit a little more to help further clarify what you are asking for.  Feel free to toll back the edit if I didn't capture what you were trying to ask,

Comment: @Noitidart but now that I look at the clarified question, the functionality you want exists as part of the existing "Linked" question.  Look at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more- for example.  Each of the questions in the "Linked" section are actually "Linkers" per your definition.

Comment: Ah you're right! Thanks very much @psubsee2003! It might have been nice to show an icon saying "linked FROM external topic TO HERE" OR "linked FROM HERE and TO external topic". Do you think worth it? Im not sure maybe not worth the trouble. Thanks for your beutiful edit to my question with image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functionality you are asking for already exists as part of the linked question list.  Not to pick on any questions, but take [Flagging migration should include more options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options) as an example.

If you look at the sidebar

[image: linked questions from example post]

You will find a list of 6 different questions, none of which appear as links within the current question.  But if you go to each linked question, you will see each of those questions is linked to the original question (some of which are closed as duplicates), which is the exact behavior you are looking for.

And for cases, when there are too many linked questions to fit in the sidebar, there will be a link added to the side bar call "see more linked questions"

[image: see more linked questions]

Which just links to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/<question number>`, so you can scan through all of the linked question.

---

The only difference from the current design and your proposal is there is not a separate section.  While I can see it might be easier to understand which direction the link is, I don't think there is enough benefit to make it worth further cluttering up the side bar.

Comment: Thank you! PS: via this way I just found my "topic YYY" hahaha :P (for you and anyone that understood my xxx yyy bs :P hahaha)