# Find a later question that refers to a question of interest to you

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When lawyers cite a decision of a court, they can find out easily whether someone cited that decision in a subsequent decision.  That is, they can track a case through later references to it.

Is there a way to find out if a given question has been referred to subsequently on SO?

Obviously, if you find a useful answer you would like to see where others have gone beyond it or distinguished it.

Comment: I believe "Linked Questions" in the right sidebar shows questions that _linked to_ the question at hand.

Comment: @Kendra I believe the OP want's it the other way round. Having a question at hand, and check, if it was used to mark another question as duplicate.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The "Linked" section shows the same. It's just all bundled. See my answer, and the question I linked from there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look in the right sidebar of a question, you'll see "Related" questions listed. Above that, on certain questions, you'll see "Linked" questions listed. These are questions that either posted a link (in answers, comments, or the question) to the question you are viewing, or are linked to in the questions (or answers or comments) on the question you're viewing.

See the discussion [here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265520/similar-to-linked-section-but-linkers)
If you go look at that question, look at the "Linked" section. You'll notice this question is listed there.

Also note that a question closed as a duplicate will have the target/duplicate linked here as well.

Links remain even if the post is reopened or the link in the post is removed later.

Comment: thank you.  Now I know, and am even more impressed by SO!

Comment: The link remains even after it is deleted.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Thanks for confirming. I thought so, but I couldn't remember for sure.