# Propose Close -> Migration options based on tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

I've read [Flagging migration should include more options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options) and understand that migration targets are based on migration statistics (i.e. number of approved migrations).

Instead of providing more options, I would propose a somewhat *different* option: **to have some tags associated with their most probable migration destination**.

For example, an off-topic question with the `[android]` tag is likely to be a candidate for migration to http://android.stackexchange.com. And therefore, it would be logical if this option appeared when selecting the "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" close reason.

Same would apply to, say `[linux]`, `[ubuntu]`, `[apple]`, `[tex]`, ...

These links might be cumbersome to implement/maintain, but I think they could be useful.

Comment: Was already about to write this question myself, when I found yours. Sad no-one took note of it though.

Comment: @FD_ Yeah, I though it could be useful. But obviously most people didn't feel that way, heh

Comment: Couldn't agree more. After clicking about 100 times - if not more -  on `Offtopic -> Belongs on another site in the network` only to discover for the 100th time that [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) and [IT security](http://security.stackexhchange.com) or non the list. I guess the problem is that SO only caters for the most common tags, for which the list of 5 sites is adequate.

Comment: I think this is a great solution that I was about to leave as an answer on that original thread but found this question on the comment link. The citation on that question is that they use percentages to discover the top migrations. I think this is a bit flawed because the other options aren't available; most notably the mobile questions or it security. Therefore I think what happens is no one flags them and moves on.

Comment: I totally agree. And code-review should almost always be included because many questions related to different languages are not: How can I fix the bug? rather than Is there a better way?

Comment: Still a big problem. This is mainly a big problem for me since I just look at the crypto questions that pop up. So if I have to migrate I always have to copy my off topic reason from a text file, not the right way to go.

Comment: I was also about to write this question, just now. Over five years, it has not been handled...