# Can't users who report a duplicate also post a link to which it is duplicate of?

Tags: discussion

I have this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266643/why-is-the-migrate-to-option-not-there-for-android-enthusiasts) here which was marked as duplicate. But what's more annoying to see that no one bothered to post where it is duplicate and of which question is it duplicate of. Simply posting a question duplicate makes no sense until you provide a link to which question is it duplicate of?

Comment: You don't see this at the top of the question: 

This question already has an answer here:

    Flagging migration should include more options 2 answers

Comment: You mean like the big box at the top of the question that says "This question already has an answer here: [Flagging migration should include more options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options)"?

Comment: Can you provide some input on how exactly you were able to miss that box, please? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267318/476 Honest UI improvement question, not trying to be sarcastic.

Comment: @deceze exactly previously it was like duplicate of  and then the duplicate link comes up.

Comment: Would be great if you could post a comment on that other thread detailing from a user perspective how you perceived that situation and why you failed to notice the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

> [image]

There is a link. Right at the top of the question:

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>   Link to question *n answers*

Comment: That FHRC is a thing of beauty.

Comment: @JonK - I used my non-dominant hand too ;)

Comment: @JonK true, looks almost too perfect! :D