# "This question already has an answer here" banner too easy to miss

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, user-interface

I have noticed what [this user here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267315/476) reports a few times recently: people failing to see the "This question already has an answer here" banner on closed duplicates. They'll complain in the comments, or editing their question with their complaint, or post on Meta, because all they seem to notice is the close reason box underneath their question, but not the banner pointing them to the duplicate at the top.

That is somewhat understandable, since the two can be very far apart. Users may also not actually scroll back to the top of the page, because they keep an eye on the comments only, and that's where they notice the close reason box. They may also mistake that banner for advertisement and [not actually read it](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/banner-blindness-old-and-new-findings/). A bit of a UI improvement seems in order here.

How about also including a link to the duplicate inside the close reason box?

> marked as duplicate by Jon Skeet Jul 24 at 8:14
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer here:
>
> - How to foo a bar?
>
> If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

---

Cases in point:

> could you please add the link to the original question mine is
> duplicating maybe the answers there would of help – Twista [7 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702593/why-does-connect-error-seem-to-return-a-boolean-type#comment94260240_53702593)
>
> can you refer me to another thread since you marked this as
> duplicate? Cant seem to find any thread with my requirement (using PHP
> variable to output different oninvalid values) – Emil Budev [39 secs ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250679/change-standard-password-validation-error-based-on-php-variable?noredirect=1#comment95329653_54250679)
>
> @john-conde Which one share the link too – Ask SNB [6 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208468/how-do-i-extract-simple-data-from-json-with-php#comment97152970_55208468)
>
> This might be duplicate but it will be helpful if u add some solution – ganesh [2 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55333746/getting-a-syntax-error-while-using-the-spread-operator#comment97392675_55333746)
>
> @deceze It's etiquette to point to the question I'm duplicating... – Enrique Alcazar [11 secs ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512053/what-does-return-x-in-y-and-z-mean-in-python?noredirect=1#comment97729627_55512053)
>
> can you please send link of that question – rupali [18 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220933/how-can-i-get-the-month-name-from-the-month-number-with-year#comment99062330_56220933)

Comment: I have missed this banner because-

I read the whole post from the start and as the post ends in the last with a marked as duplicate Banner my reading stops abruptly  i.e. i missed what was there in the first part considering it as an advertisement banner.

If you are placing a duplicate of banner in the last then why don't  we have the "the question already has an answer " banner right next to  it(previously it was like- the duplicate of banner used to end with a hyperlink describing which question is it duplicate of).Then why did we change it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my "banner blindness" theory. :)

Comment: I do this all the time.  My brain has been trained to ignore most banner-like entities on websites because they are usually ads that I have no interest in.  This is a good idea.

Comment: This is incredible. We regularly get flags asking us to take down that banner because they think it was incorrectly applied. So if the duplicate is correct it disappears? Is that what people are saying?

Comment: Banner blindness is a real thing.  Think of how many Bruce's we've seen and they all look the same.  We only pay attention to Hulk.

Comment: Duplicate questions that are *merged* (or any merged question for that matter) have their targets in the notice themselves, just like what you mention. Also, there is a slight grammar issue in your notice you have given; it should say "If the answers to that question do not fully address *your* question, ...".

Comment: The duplicate would be present in the comments, too, except that automatic comments from the vote to close process, *as well as other comments linking to the duplicate* are automatically deleted. :(  (Pet peeve of mine, because I *used to* edit the "Possible duplicate of …" comments to include context, or to explain any superficial differences, if it seemed useful.  E.g., "Possible duplicate of …. That's about frobbing a bar; you're doing that indirectly by passing null to the frobulator construct which frobs the bar for you.")

Comment: @Josh Really? I didn't know that other comments were also deleted.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi I don't know if it's actually *every* comment that links to it, but it's gets at least: the plain automatically generated comment, edited automatically generated comments, and some comments that link to the question, or mention duplicate.  I asked about it before (on meta.tex: [why was “possible duplicate” comment with additional information deleted?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3786/29288)), but did't get the exact details.  Also see this feature request: [Don't delete comments with link to duplicate if they are modified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141414/225437).

Comment: The [answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3787/29288) to the question I got was sort of unsatisfying: "The 'system' now deletes comments which it detects point to a dupe when a duplicate is marked: thus anything saying 'May be a dupe ...' or 'Dupe of ...' gets zapped. The logic is not fool-proof: if you have a longer more complex comment it will be missed, while comments pointing to alternatives to the dupe actually picked can get removed!"  So, the current system intentionally removes one of the places where users would see what the duplicate is, and possibly valuable information.

Comment: @Josh What do you think about my answer?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Seconded. Most times, I edit the robotic "Possible duplicate of" comment with a more contextual message and some starting tips. If that information is lost, I may have to rethink my strategy.

Comment: BTW, while we're at it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267477/how-many-badges-are-there-on-so#comment71167_267478 The banner blindness is rampant! O_O

Comment: Related on Meta Super User: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1614/closed-as-exact-duplicate-by-suggestion

Comment: [Yet another instance of banner blindness](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269725/when-a-question-is-marked-as-a-duplicate-why-does-it-not-include-a-link-to-the)...

Comment: There's now a feature request on Meta Stack Exchange very similar to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239097/link-to-duplicate-answer-in-marked-as-duplicate-section

Comment: Obligatory hilarious example of "banner blindness", for those unfamiliar with the term, that was in Hot Network Questions a few months ago: https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/120541/47336

Comment: One possible inexpensive tweak: Change **has been asked before and already has an answer.**  --- to --- **has been asked before and already [has an answer here](https://link-to-anchor-at-top-of-page)**, linking to an anchor that points to the banner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Post Notices (Closed/On Hold/etc.) rolling out on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390887/new-post-notices-closed-on-hold-etc-rolling-out-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: It's still in A/B Testing stage. You should use [meta-tag:status-review]

Answer (score 14):

I agree with you, but there are some wrinkles that need to be ironed out in order for this to work:

On questions that are *merged* (either in addition to or instead of being closed as a duplicate), the link to the merge target is in the merge notice itself:

> ### **merged** by Moderator just now
>
> this question was merged with [Link to and title of some other question] because it is an exact duplicate of that question.

(note the casing issue on that sentence; [that's a completely irrelevant issue that the SE team has been unwilling to fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134328/description-in-post-merge-notice-should-have-a-sentence-cap-like-every-other-pos).)

Additionally, duplicate questions whose targets have no upvoted or accepted answer (can only be done by moderators (except on meta sites)) show the following banner instead of the usual one:

> **This question is an exact duplicate of:**
> [list]

...in which case we should show a banner like the following one:

> ### **marked** as duplicate by OneUser, TwoUsers, ThreeUsers, FourUsers, FiveUsers just now
>
> This question is an exact duplicate of another question that has been previously asked on this site:
>
> - [link to and title of question]
>
> If this question is not the same as yours, please [edit your question to explain how it is different or] ask a new question.

(in the above sentence, the part in brackets is only shown to the author of the question.)

Also, another possible thing we may need to consider is that there is another notice:

> **This question *may already have* an answer here:**
> [list]

...that is *only shown to the author of the question* if there are pending votes to close or recommend closure flags against it, but not enough to close the question (italics are mine). Possible duplicate comments will be on the question, but may not be seeable if there are lots of comments or the voter or flagger manually deleted the comment. In this case, I think that we should show a "post notice"-style banner to the author without headings:

> Your question *may* have already been answered here:
>
> - [list]
>
> If the answers at the above linked question do not answer your question, please consider editing it to explain how it is different. Otherwise, your question may be closed if it already does have an answer there.

This will remind the asker to consider editing his question and that his question is not yet closed.

One more thing to add to the mix is old links that were edited directly into the question by the Community user instead of placed above the question body in a banner. Such links look like:

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [list without answer count]

In that case, I think that it would be hard to glean the link from the added comment, especially if it was edited by someone else afterwards. However, these changes may not affect that, and I think so because most of these old questions have a different close reason *internally* on them ("exact duplicate" as opposed to "duplicate" on newer questions with banners).

Lastly, I think that in all other cases, I think that the notice should look like this:

> ### **marked** as duplicate by OneUser, TwoUsers, ThreeUsers, FourUsers, FiveUsers just now
>
> This question has previously been asked on this site and already has an answer here:
>
> - [list]
>
> If none of the answers there address your question, please [edit your question to explain how it is different or] ask a new question.

(and of course, in that last sentence, the part in brackets is only shown to the question's author.)

I am ambivalent as to whether or not we should continue to show the old banner alongside the new notice, but if you have any opinion, please comment.

Comment: FWIW, I think the issue is mostly related to Mjölnir insta-closing. The other cases, especially the old manual ones, don't really need to be considered all that much. Very thorough rundown though, nice.

Comment: My eyes almost skipped past this answer because of all the realistic "Marked as Duplicate" banners. Ah, conditioning!

Comment: On merge notice sentence capitalization: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134328/description-in-post-merge-notice-should-have-a-sentence-cap-like-every-other-pos

Comment: @BoltClock Why has the SE team been so unveiling to fix it? I noticed it's been duplicated many times and bountied once, but still no response.

Comment: Oh, and I should mention that the team recommends that we should report trivial issues as they are easy to fix, rather than not report such issues at all.

Comment: @BoltClock unwilling* (stop it, AutoCorrect :)