# How many badges are there on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, badges

What are they all, are there more than the three metals, gold, silver and bronze and is there a list?

Answer (score 3):

The full list of badges is at https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges. There you can see which badges you have earned, and what it takes to earn the ones you don't have yet.

Comment: ahh, great thanks! I thought they were secretive!

Comment: @user They're a menu item in the main menu...!

Comment: which 'main menu'?

Comment: It's the fourth gray button to the right of the "stackoverflow" logo and name on every page. I have to admit, I never paid much attention to that myself (aka "banner blindness").

Comment: @user Pretty much the only menu there is on the site. The one that also contains the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: Wow, I've never seen that before! I think the same reason as @AndrewMedico - banner blindness! I consider the black bar across the top as a menu as well

Comment: For even more in depth stuff, look at the [MSE List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)