# What does " ̸ Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege" mean?

Tags: discussion

I've started noticing a (recent?) addition to the closed post banner:

[image: ̸ Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege]

To me, this reads like the *question itself* will no longer be visible to lower-rep users, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  If I'm not logged in, I can still see the post just fine (directly and in SO searches and on the tag listing page).  So what does this bold banner mean?  Does it just mean that only the author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege can see who voted for its closure?

That seems like a rather minor detail to flag with such a bold message.

Comment: Not the question, just the lower block of the close message. To be specific, that text prefixed by the message you've quoted.

Comment: Here the announcement regarding this new feature: [New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013)

Comment: It's refering to the bit of the message below the horizontal rule [[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow#comment1118639_337013) (reply 3 comments below when showing all comments)]

Comment: Just a guess, the message is what is not view-able to everyone else, not the question.

Comment: Makes sense.  Those comments could be answers.