# "Does this answer your question?" duplicate comment text is silly and confusing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, duplicate-questions

The auto-comment text for *close-as-duplicate* votes is very confusing, particularly for new users.

Here's a typical interaction I'm seeing associated with *"Does this answer your question?"*

> [image]

<sub>Reference: [gmap icon from assets in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58848627/283366)</sub>

I'm frankly getting tired of editing these comments to make it clear they are associated with a moderation action.

I'm not sure what the problem was with *"Possible duplicate of..."* but this is not solving it. Can we make it clearer that the comment means something more like...

> This question has a possible answer here - <link>. If so, it should be closed as a duplicate

and not some invitation for extended conversation.

---

#### Edit

Just found [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390894/283366) which mirrors my sentiments and does a much better job of providing an alternate (albeit lengthy) response.

Is this open to discussion at all?

Comment: Adding the feature request tag.  This is a bad change and should be reverted.  Now when I flag a dupe OP wants to engage in a conversation - because they think I've asked a question (Did this answer your question?) when I'm really trying to say "This question *is* a duplicate".  It's confusing and misleading.

Comment: @J... Sorry, but from what I've read on Meta SE it's very unlikely this will be changed. But at least we can manually edit the auto-comment...

Comment: "Is this open to discussion at all?" Has anything been for the last year or so?

Comment: The current (new) wording seems snark-adjacent to me.

Comment: *and not some invitation for extended conversation.* **this**

Comment: I'm in the same boat; editing every single auto-comment made when I vote to close as dupe to say more clearly "this is a [possible] duplicate of X". Very annoying.

Comment: This is on our list to address. Will have more updates here when we get to it. If this is generating more work for folks when that is not the intention, we'll revisit.

Comment: Just found this. Editing the auto-comment is an excellent work-around, but in my case, I didn't even see the auto-comment until I had added a similar comment. I HAPPENED to refresh the page and see that I added two comments. "I must have pointed this out ages ago", I thought, only to see that I had made the comment 39 seconds ago. :scratch head: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540197

Answer (score 60):

Having the site make a request on my behalf is off-putting at best and super annoying at worst. And that's what this canned comment does: it asks something of the user and sticks my name next to it.

When I close as a duplicate, I'm not asking, I'm telling.

I would find text like, "This question is similar; please differentiate your question if you believe it's not a duplicate," more acceptable to me and more useful to the user.

Comment: Or even just, "I believe this answers your question: <link>". I agree with you that the comment needs to be making a *statement*, not asking a question. I'm not interested in starting a dialogue.

Comment: @CodyGray - Or "This question's answers may answer your question: <link>" Or even more: "This question's answers may answer your question: <link> Please have a look, and if it does, click the [whatever it is] link at the top of your question."

Comment: I like the idea of alluding to questions being *similar* and motivating the OP to *differentiate*. That gives some wiggle room, but directs the action to clarifying the question instead of arguing with the voter.

Answer (score 27):

I agree with [erickson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393427/157247) that having it ask a question on my behalf doesn't sit well.

How about a direct statement, with instructions saying what to do if the voter is right:

> This question's answers may answer your question: [*Why did the chicken cross the road?*](http://example.com) Please have a look, and if that does answer your question, click the [whatever it is] link at the top of your question to mark your question answered.

Answer (score 7):

I had no idea they changed the wording, mostly because I'm a moderator so I never get to leave these comments anymore. That looks like a significant improvement over the old wording, honestly — I find myself saying something along the lines of the new wording fairly often, when I'm electing not to use my binding vote. "Possible duplicate" sends an unpleasant message to users that they either wasted their (own or the community's) time, or broke the rules, by asking their question, even though that was never our intended message. If anything, *I* found myself frequently having to change it before I became a moderator, and frequently eschewing it when composing comments manually after.

I agree that the current wording doesn't make sense in the middle of a conversation like this, though. It only really makes sense as a standalone question, or less commonly as a conversation *finisher* in very limited contexts. If you're finding yourself having to change this message frequently, I would support another change to the default text, but I don't have any suggestions.

I also agree with ImportanceOfBeingErnest that this comment simply doesn't make sense when generated in conjunction with a binding vote (as I said above, I take the time to write a manual one when I elect not to use my vote). Apparently the system leaves these comments up now instead of deleting them as soon as it posts them with binding votes. I get that closing and opening are both temporary states that can be toggled at a whim, but I really don't think the mechanical song and dance needs to happen in the first place.

Comment: *""Possible duplicate" sends an unpleasant message to users that they either wasted their (own or the community's) time ... by asking their question"* - of course, this is often true.

Comment: Avoiding unpleasantness at all costs is a paved road to hell.  Can we just give out a welcome kit with peril sensitive sunglasses and a course of methadone instead?

Comment: Such "possible duplicate" comments can have a pedagogic value; next time, an affected user may spend their time in searching the site before posting a question…

Answer (score 3):

It fits well when the question is unclear, but *seems* to be a duplicate. I mean, if I need to pick a close reason, might as well pick the most constructive one, but ask to be safe.

But as you said, in most cases it's unnecessary. If I'm voting to close, I'm making a statement, not asking a question.

However, *flagging* to close, for users with less than 10k rep, is a bit different, so maybe flags could generate the question verbiage, and votes could generate the statement verbiage? Just an idea.

On that note, maybe it would be useful to allow 10k+ users to *flag* for closure, instead of being required to vote, but that's another topic.

Lastly, just to add my proposal for the verbiage:

> It seems like this question has already been asked and answered: <link>. If this answers your question too, please <click some button to accept the duplicate>, otherwise [edit] your question to clarify what's different.

Answer (score -15):

> Does this answer your question?

Reading this, after flagging a question, has several positive micro effects.

The haste in interacting within the topic is decreased, resulting in a more welcoming and empathic participation. I think by taking a step back and asking yourself whether this specific question in doubt is really a duplicate, encourages the close-voter to put one more moment of effort into understanding the OP's requirement. Instead of instantly shutting down a question, a new path of communication and finding a solution is given chance to develop.

Comment: How does reading an automatically posted comment phrased in the form of a question cause any of the things you mention to happen?

Comment: @CodyGray the same reason as why placebos work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it. Placebos work because you *believe* that they work, which is enough to overcome psychological symptoms, some of which may even be causing physiological ones. I don't know what in the world that has to do with a comment phrased in the form of a question. Are you saying that if I *believe* hard enough that the question is a duplicate, then it will become one?