# Is asking the community to find (not recommend) an off-site resource allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons, help-center, recommendation-questions

Up until about a year and a half ago, one of our standard close reasons was:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

This was [changed in 2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390887/6471538) to:

> We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. You can edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations.

Somewhat hidden within this change was the removal of the "find" aspect to the original close reason. This implies that off-site resource requests that involve a non-opinion-based search for a known, definite thing (e.g. "What is the latest release of DJGPP and where is the official download?", "What is the name and official mailing address of the current publisher of K&R?", or "Was there ever an official release of Delphi for SunOS?") used to be closable but now are no longer closable unless they meet some *other* close reason such as needing details or clarity or being about general computing. The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), however, continues to use the old close reason ("recommend or find") rather than the new "seeking recommendations" one.

A [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390887/new-post-notices-closed-on-hold-etc-rolling-out-on-stack-overflow#comment738044_390887) from a staff member on the question linked above says:

> The actual root reasons have not changed, but the labels and descriptions have all been adjusted – Yaakov Ellis♦

This comment implies that the underlying close reason is the same in substance (though reworded), but that doesn't explain the blatant omission of the "find" aspect. It's also unclear if the word of this staff member represents community consensus on scope or simply a statement of desire or direction.

Are requests to find (not recommend) off-site resources currently allowed on Stack Overflow? If they are, can we edit the help center? If not, can we change the current close reason to reflect this?

To be clear, I'm not asking about resource *recommendation* questions like "What is a good X library for accomplishing Y on Z?", but about questions where there is likely to be a single, definitive answer such as "This software was discontinued in 2003, the last release version was 5.3.32 and can be downloaded from the company's official archive here...." or "The address of the publisher as of March 6, 2021 is Core Dump Publishers, 255 Register Bank Street, Programmertown 32767.".

Comment: That whole change occurred at a time where frictions between users and staff were about at all time high. To me it seems little attention was paid to user feedback at the time. I personally have never found the newer reasons to be as clear as what they replaced and in fact somewhat ambiguous such as the "more focused" reasoning. Would be great if it was put on the roadmap to revisit them at some time and make them more definitive and less ambiguous

Comment: The [on topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) still says: "Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above: … 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." There is a small carve-out to that for requests for *official* resources to be on-topic, which shog9 is a proponent for.

Comment: I generally refer to [this question as the canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385479/215552); it was only asked a couple of years ago, so I don't think it's _that_ old that we need to revisit the entire question.

Comment: @charlietfl: And perhaps with actual [usability testing](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) (I could be wrong, of course).

Comment: Nits in case this question becomes a sign post: "*definite thing (e.g. "What is the latest release of* " If "the latest" isn't also the last, I wouldn't call this a good example of a "definite thing".

Comment: It's all off-topic, it has always been. If it was to change, we would need a broad community consensus for it. Not just yet another poorly considered silent change by the company. People will still moderate as before. Why they changed all the wording to something far worse, I have no idea.

Comment: I think either Shog9 or Tim had a Meta post on this at some point while they were still CMs, but I can't remember where it is.

Comment: That last hypothetical question is probably more appropriate on Retro Computing or some 'history of computing' Stack than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 42):

Without a recommendation it would have to be a specific off-site resource and the answer would simply be a single link. Like for example: "Q: Where can I find the official Python documentation, googling for it didn't help? A: There it is.".

It's unlikely that using search engines searching for a specific off-site resource didn't help, so such a service wouldn't be needed very often.

And while we could in principle do it without opionated answers (there would be only one valid answer anyway) it would reduce us to maintainers of link lists. I don't think this should be part of Stack Overflow. Search engines or other special resources (for example awesome lists on Github) do that job much better. Just asking for a simple link to a specific off-site resource is not a good fit for a knowledge library of Q&A (maybe chat would be a suitable place).

Therefore, no, it shouldn't be allowed. The old close reasons still apply. When the wording got changed in 2019, the descriptions got shorter but maybe not better. They should be reverted or improved instead.

Comment: Maybe tag wikis would be suitable places for links to specific off-site resources. However, I never really read tag wikis a lot. It might not be a place where many people look.

Comment: Tag wikis are pretty specific, they're probably not for everything, but when they work they're amazing. I'm pretty sure I discovered a whole lot from [tag:c++].

Comment: While don't think these requests should be on-topic, I disagree with the reasoning in this answer. Not everything is a simple to find as the python docs. There *are* lots of resources that are hard to find using a search engine, and still relevant for programmers. They might not be indexed or hidden in documents with some obscure format, they might no longer exist on the web (but only in some archives), they might not exist in the web at all (IRC chat logs, mailing lists etc). And then there's completely off-line resources like printed books.

Comment: @Bergi I see your point. How would you propose to make the hard to find resources questions ontopic but the easy to find resources, google that for me, questions offtopic? I guess it's difficult to differentiate and we would either need to allow both or disallow both. On the other hand if the resource no longer exists on the web, it might be something for retrocomputing.stackexchange.

Comment: @PasserBy "..when they work they're amazing." Yes, for some reason I ignored them for many years. Maybe they could play a more important role in the UI, so that people feel more compelled to look at them. I always thought SO is not like Wikipedia, but tag wikis are.

Comment: Actually, while mentioning retrocomputing, I remembered that had such an example (asking for sources of the curses library) that helped me there. So maybe I should rethink this answer here. However, people already voted on it, so I should not edit it. So maybe, asking for definite resources could be on-topic, if people would present their extensive search activity before. There is more burden than benefit in maintaining links that are easy to find elsewhere but there is value in experts sharing the location of difficult to find resources.

Comment: @Trilarion I'm torn myself. If we wanted to ban these questions, we'd miss some useful resources, but if we wanted to allow them it would be hard to draw a line.

Answer (score 13):

The original wording was better because it included some reasoning for why the question was a bad fit for the site.  As inconvenient as it is, I agree 100% with that reasoning - Stack Overflow is not set up to be the arbiter of a popularity contest.  The noise generated by arguments back and forth can be detrimental to the site, and the accepted or most popular answer can be misleading in a given situation.

But I think an exception could be made for any question that has an objective criteria for picking a single correct answer.  The examples you gave are decent illustrations of this.

I don't expect this opinion to be popular but I thought it should be expressed.

Comment: The exception mentioned here would just feed the review queue for the Outdated Answers project. For two reasons: `1` An objectively correct answer to the question "What's the latest version of xyz?" can become objectively incorrect a minute after it was posted. `2` An objectively correct answer to the question "Where can I download the latest version of xyz?" can consist of a dead link a minute after it was posted.

Comment: @IInspectable: fortunately the tag pages for C and C++ do contain external links with last (and older versions) of the drafts for standard! Searching them in Google links to... the official versions that can be buyed on ISO site! Of course it needs some housekeeping to add new versions but as long as some members do it, all others can benefit. It is true that last version should be seen as *at the date of the answer* but it may contain valuable information!