# Questions about licensing

Tags: support, scope, help-center

Are questions about software licensing off-topic for Stack Overflow? I read this before and I assume it is true but which sentence/paragraph from Help Center or which answer from meta can be cited to prove this?

I checked https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and some other pages but I could not find a direct hint.

Comment: It's in the tag wiki. "This tag should be used for questions about software that *provides* licensing services, such as a licensing server or client. Don't use this tag to ask for legal advice about licensing."

Comment: *Makes note to clean up licensing tag again.*

Comment: None of the answers here mention our sibling site for legal questions [law.se], but depending on your question, it might be relevant. As always, please review the site's posting guidelines and check for existing questions about your topic before plunging ahead.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Software licensing is not on topic, as it is not a practical programming problem. We don't list it explicitly, because such a list of everything not on topic would be prohibitively long.

[Software Engineering](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) (formerly Programmers) is [in the process of getting community support behind updating their interstitial page](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8056/new-site-name-and-scope-proposals), and software licensing will no longer be on-topic there, either.

Such questions are on-topic at [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) - see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308750/1677912).

Comment: Note that Programmers considering it "on-topic" still doesn't mean it's a good idea to take legal advice from strangers on the Internet.

Comment: I just tried to move such a question to Programmers by flagging it. When marking the Question as off-topic there are serveral sites I can move the issue to but Programmers is not provided as a possible selection. Why?

Comment: @Silicomancer: Programmers received too much crap from auto-migrated questions so it is not listed, and there are only a limited number of slots in that UI *anyway*. Flag with `other` and ask a moderator to review and migrate if appropriate. Remember, only (ask to) migrate quality posts.

Comment: @Silicomancer: also see [Flagging migration should include more options](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251652); Programmers fails the 'success rate' stats if listed in the menu.

Comment: *How* is it not a practical programming problem?

Comment: @SamB: licensing is not programming. Licensing is also not unique to programming.

Comment: I really do wish I could file bug reports against lawyers.  But then they would probably charge me an arm and a leg just to schedule the fix.

Comment: ServerFault also has a good [canonical question](https://serverfault.com/q/215405/55514) on the systems side of licensing, ie licence management.  Because it's a canonical question, further such questions are off-topic there, but it may be of use to you depending on the exact nature of your query.

Answer (score 27):

Questions about software licensing are off-topic here at Stack Overflow because they do not solve a direct problem about programming. But don't lose hope! You can ask at...

## [Open Source!](http://opensource.stackexchange.com)

First off, I'm a pro tem moderator at Open Source, and I can tell you that we accept nearly any question that has to do with software licensing. We accept questions that vary from complying with various licenses, and we even allow ["license recommendations"](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/463/how-do-i-ask-for-a-license-recommendation): recommendation questions that ask the community to recommend a license based on certain criteria.

I can't wait to see you there!

Comment: What if the OP wants to release software as closed source; is that okay, too?

Comment: @tripleee As long as there is an open source element to the question, it should be fine. :)

Comment: @Zizous212 Actually, I'm looking at a question which doesn't, and am unsure what to recommend; viz. [this question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/38177602/which-license-should-i-use-for-non-commercial-use)

Answer (score 7):

I want to add some clarity about Software licensing questions being on-topic on [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) because there seems to be some confusion.

In general:

- Licensing questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow, period. See @MartijnPieters's accepted answer.
- **Programmers are not lawyers.**

  - Therefore, questions about licensing can only be ones that **most expert programmers** can reasonably expected to answer.
  - Also, **Programmers are not lawyers** and therefore cannot be expected to give legal advice.
- Questions about licensing are also bound by the standards that apply to *every other question on the Stack Exchange network*, i.e. "Will this question be useful to future readers, or only to you?"
- Finally, readers interested in this topic should [**read the SoftwareEngineering.SE FAQ**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7265/88986) which clarifies which questions are on topic and which are off topic. In particular, it attempts to address the seemingly self-contradictory help center on that site - it's not self-contradictory, it can just seem that way at first glance. Read the FAQ.

Additionally, I strongly recommend that anyone referring people to Software Engineering Stack Exchange keep two things in mind:

- [What goes on SoftwareEngineering.SE? A Guide for Stack Overflow.](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/88986)

  - Make sure the question meets SoftwareEngineering scope and quality guidelines.
- [Stack Exchange's policy on cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info), e.g. please tell them to delete the Stack Overflow question when asking them to ask on SoftwareEngineering.

Comment: freshly public beta OpenSource.SE does accept licensing questions.

Comment: @ratchetfreak **All** licensing questions, including [ones like this?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/74648/do-i-need-to-contact-a-lawyer-to-report-a-gpl-violation-in-software-distributed)

Comment: @durron597 You bet!

Comment: Maybe also mention that even informal legal advice needs to mention which jurisdiction(s) it applies to, and ideally also mention the relevant statutes.