# Should we add an off-topic close reason to specifically address legal requests?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, custom-close-reasons

Thanks to our benevolent SE overlords, 10k+ users now have access to a new [question close statistics tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257449/188673)! Among other features, it provides a list of all the *custom* close reasons used to close questions, and on Stack Overflow specifically, it would seem that questions asking for legal advice are especially common.

[image: custom close reasons]

Indeed, if one takes the time to add up all the times a custom close reason was used, it comes up to **nearly 300 times**. This is actually more than the "professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration" close reason, which as of this writing has only been used 233 times.

Perhaps it is time to add a legal-related off-topic close reason? The second most commonly used reason is a reasonable base template, but it could certainly be improved with some more description, links, and perhaps a canonical Meta post.

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: And which reason would this replace? We have a limited number of spaces so if we add one, another needs to go.

Comment: Ummm 20K+ users :(

Comment: @bluefeet Perhaps one that is the least used? I'm not 10k so I don't have access to this new tool, but I would've thought that you could easily find out the *least* used option.

Comment: @bluefeet What exactly is the reason for that? Is that just a hard limit in the current SE software? Either way, you *could* make it fit in a few different ways, I guess. Perhaps the easiest one would be merging the Super User/Server Fault off-topic reasons.

Comment: @MartinJames It's 10k+, not 20k. The SO page is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats).

Comment: @bluefeet - Is it really the case where we cannot add this in without replacing something?

Comment: @bluefeet - If one had to go, I would say it should be site migration "This question belongs on another exchange" because that close reason is so broken I honestly cannot fathom why it still exists.

Comment: @TravisJ Probably design aesthetics more than anything; the design of SE/SO is simple, we don't need it cluttered (not implying that adding the additional close reason would make it cluttered).

Comment: @TravisJ I'm playing devil's advocate here. We have limited space in the UI. So if that space remains small, something has to give.  I think it's a valid question.

Comment: I'd rather get rid of the free range "This is offtopic because the sky is blue" and replace it with a generic "This is an off topic question as defined in the Stack OVerflow help center" and then use the help center to convey that legal questions are off topic.

Comment: @bluefeet - Okay, that's fair. Looking at some stats (I have a personal stats page now :P) it appears that most sites use the off topic -> migrate selection 0.00% and that even on StackOverflow it is only used 0.34% of the time in closures. I believe this makes a strong case for removing it, especially considering that custom reasons are used more commonly than the migration reason and also that migration does not include an option to actually select the proper exchange. It is probably more likely that custom reasons are used for migration more often than the actual migration option.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I disagree, honestly. People asking those kinds of off-topic questions aren't going to read the help center, anyway, they're just going to get frustrated and leave.

Comment: @AlexisKing If they aren't going to read it anyway, then why should any of our close reasons link to the help center? Why don't we allow all questions since users clearly don't read anyway?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - I disagree as well. I don't see it being misused in the statistics page. The perhaps closest to that is "close because it is not a question" as a custom reason. No one seems to have ever entered "the sky is blue" as a valid close reason.

Comment: @TravisJ It's around here somewhere, but Shog9 had a meta post that detailed a non trivial amount of abuse in the custom close reason.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Because giving someone the gist of why their question was off-topic is good, and for the small portion who actually wants to learn more, the help center is available. Just throwing up a vague "read this small novel to figure out why your question was closed" statement is not helpful.

Comment: @TravisJ While I agree that the migration stuff needs work, removing that option will only increase the # of custom flags that moderators get.  In the past 90 days that's 103 flags to Stats, 86 flags to DBA, 75 to MSO, etc, etc, etc and voting to close because something belongs on another site, just leads to messy cross-posts that mods on multiple sites have to deal with. I'm not sure removing that is that option is ideal in many ways.

Comment: I agree with @bluefeet if only for the MSO migration reason. The other reasons are... sketchy at best, but automatic migration to Meta is a good thing, imo.

Comment: @bluefeet - I do not think that removing it would affect the number of flags you get for migration because a large amount of migration targets are not covered at all by the migration reason and as a result removing it will not have any affect on a large amount of migration flags or requests.

Comment: @TravisJ How do you figure that? If we remove a standard migration list, then all those would be flagged for a moderator to move or do you just think that people will leave the off-topic questions here on SO?

Comment: @bluefeet - I definitely would not want to burden moderators with more work if it were avoidable. If you think that this path is important enough that it saves time then perhaps it is not a viable option for removal. Although I am curious how effective the close reason is if people still flag for migration to sites that are already in the preset list.

Comment: Speaking to past discussions, especially on "thought experiments", this one pertains to the comment about allowing all questions (i.e. no closures) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286407/1026459

Comment: @GeorgeStocker If we didn't have the blue-sky close reason, we would lose out on the kinds of data that prompted this question.

Comment: 300 times doesn't seem like very much, surely...

Comment: @bluefeet The popup box could be made bigger. The 5 could be set to 6. UI concerns are not the issue here.

Answer (score 27):

There is a currently active effort to close all the off-topic law-questions (copyright and licensing):

[This tag should not be [legal]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295117)

When it winds down, custom reasons relating to law will be getting as scarce as normal again.

---

Just for fun, the most used custom reasons just now:

- 104 I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for legal advice.
- 35 I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing, not programming or software development. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.
- 22 This question is off-topic because it's about licensing and copyright law, not programming.
  *(I think I'm the only one who actually entered this one manually. Once.)*
- 21 I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing, not programming or software development. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details.
- 18 I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions about licensing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/369450) are off-topic. Licensing questions [may be on-topic at Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7265/69573).

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. You might be right, in which case this point is moot.

Comment: There will always be questions asking about legal advice.

Comment: @cybermonkey, But only a few, and those can be closed with a custom reason.

Comment: There was a minor typo in one of the manually entered close reasons. Where possible, I clicked it nevertheless because it was faster than entering my own :) Alas, it's not in this list.

Answer (score 14):

These are bogus statistics.  You can easily tell:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions about licensing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/369450) are off-topic. Licensing questions [may be on-topic at Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7265/69573).

Number 3 with 15 votes with that **exact** text

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing, not programming or software development. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Number 4 with 12 votes.

The odds that *more* than one SO-user typed these exact phrases are zero.  This is just **one** SO-user adding these custom close reasons, copy/pasting the text repeatedly.  He is doing the rough equivalent of burninating tags, using a Google search to look for keywords and applying the close reason to every question that matches.

Which makes it also very likely that the "legal advice" reason got the same treatment.  Note the [burn request for it that was just recently posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal), a user that follows-up on it doesn't just handle a single question.

Don't do anything drastic based on the behavior of just one or a couple of SO users.

Comment: This is the reason for so many custom close-votes on law questions just now: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal

Comment: Yes, but all of these combined have more use than the "professional networking" one, so It might a possibility to just get rid of that one, or perhaps put it in an extra sub menu, perhaps with the options for migration, which are not used that much anyhow.

Comment: Questions that were *closed* for those reasons *must* have had enough voters that agreed with them, and there is nothing to show that the agreeing voters would have all been the same on every one of those questions, so saying that it's just a few SO users is not statistically sound.

Comment: I presented evidence that the query is not statistically sound, I'm not trying to create a statistic.  It will become sound when the sample size is large enough so it can't be affected by temporary burn requests and when the results are not pigeon-holed by an *exact* text match.

Comment: @HansPassant: You can't rightly challenge statistics without properly using statistics yourself; if you're using unsound methodology to explain why you think something is unsound, you haven't made any progress.

Comment: I agree with Hans and Deduplicator, there isn't a need for this close reason.  Most of the questions I have seen going through the cleanup were written before 2012.  I don't think we get many new questions like this.

Answer (score -2):

This would be a good feature to have, and will create an 'official' signpost that users can immediately grasp *why* a question was closed instead of looking at the comments (depending of which, *could* potentially be cluttered).

<strike>There looks like there's some space on the UI that can be used for it</strike> Going in the proper menu there's very little space in the `Flag Dialog > Close Reasons > off-topic because...` menu, meaning that to implement this, we might have to bid goodbye to an existing close reason.
As discussed in the comments it seems that `Migration` could be a potential candidate, but this feature is useful for good questions that are simply asked on the wrong site.

For example, it could be:

[image]

*Just an example, should be in the proper menu.*

Some of these questions *are* on-topic over at Programmers.SE, [excerpt taken from a Meta answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic):

> As a rule of thumb, questions are on topic [at Programmers.SE] if they are answerable by
>   **expert programmers**, as opposed to **expert lawyers**.

This could potentially be aligned with finally exterminating the [legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legal) tag, as [seen here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal)

Comment: When this Burnination session started, there were **only** 457 questions tagged with `legal` - and more than half were already closed. Compare that with the total amount of questions, and you'll see adding this *specifically* into the Close Reasons box is out of all proportions (such as the pixel space it takes up, compared with the rather limited real estate size of the Close Reason dialog).

Comment: @Jongware It's not just the [tag:legal], there are more than a dozen tags covered under that burnination effort.