# Do we want a licensing off-topic reason?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope, close-reasons

The **[new 10k closing stats view](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats)** has been released recently, and going over the top custom off-topic close reasons, I see an interesting trend

```
Questions Closed    Comment
37                  I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for legal advice.
15                  I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a licensing question.
15                  I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions about licensing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/369450) are off-topic. Licensing questions [may be on-topic at Programmers.SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7265/69573).
12                  I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing, not programming or software development. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.
2                   I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about copyright / legal issues, not programming or software development. See the [help/on-topic] for more.
```

I'm sure there are many many more phrasings of the same close reason with 1 question closed each all over the place, but this may be a good indication that we want a formal close reason for questions regarding to licensing.

What say thee? Do we want an off-topic reason for licensing?

I like this wording:

> Questions related to licensing are off-topic on Stack Overflow because they are not about programming or software development. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Or something similar.

Comment: @Patrice God damn it! Well played Alexis. Well played.

Comment: Great minds think alike ;)