# Why aren't relevant tags removed if a subject is considered Off-Topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

I was about to [post a question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/removing-ads-from-open-source-projects) that touched on the edges of Software Licensing after carefully looking at the long list of Stack Exchange communities and determining that Stack Overflow would have the best demographic to answer the question. Before clicking submit, whilst double-google-checking that an answer to my question wasn't readily available, I discovered a [relevant meta question about software licensing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) which suggests Software Licensing is off-topic at Stack Overflow.

In the spirit of SE, I have since decided to [post my question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/removing-ads-from-open-source-projects) on a different StackExchange community which may arguably be more fitting, but I started to wonder: if Software Licensing is off topic, why are there so many relevant tags?

For example, in the context of my question: GPL, LGPL, Licensing

The description for the SO GPL tag states:

> **DO NOT USE, LICENSING / LEGAL ADVICE IS OFF TOPIC.** The GNU General Public License is a copyleft free software license and is the most popular open source license. This tag is for questions related to the GNU General Public License that are not requests for legal advice.

However the accepted answer, by a very reputable contributor, in the previously mentioned meta post asserts simply that:

> Software licensing is not on topic, as it is not a practical programming problem.

Like many before me, I am ultimately trying to understand why we have these 'license' tags, if questions relating to them are off-topic. If I have completely missed the point:

- Is this referenced Meta question answered in a misleading/incomplete way, or is the answer simply not authoritative?
- What types of licence questions are welcomed - and if the only acceptable type as alluded to by other licence tags is for questions relating to licensing servers, or licence system implementations; how does the fact the question is relevant to a licensing bear any difference on the practical programming problems endured once the legalities are removed, and why have specific tags like GPL and LGPL?

Comment: Software licensing questions and tags are remnants from 5+ years ago when SO just started, needed contents, and didn't have strict rule compared to now.

Comment: Thanks! That's a pretty concise and conclusive explanation to their origin - but why not remove them going forward?

Comment: Trite but true, those which fall under the on-topic guidelines are allowed. The part most likely to stop them is the last clause, which limites the other three: "and is
•a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Admittedly, that does mean all tags for specific licenses are at best legacy.

Comment: Do notice that a lot of the licensing tags got touched during [the legal cleanup](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295218/578411)

Comment: What about posing this question on programmers.stackexchange?

Comment: @Gui Because removing them and preventing their future use requires staff action to blacklist the tag.

Comment: Aside from the consequences of burninating the tags as outlined in the answers, I could also see if we got rid of it, someone unknowingly creating another.

Comment: @Trilarion Or why not just ask this question on [Open Source Stack Exchange](//opensource.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @Zizouz212 Seems to be fitting even more. If Stackoverflow regards something as off-topic, it can (and often is) be on-topic at another Stackexchange and should be asked there in the future. The only remaining question is what to do with the 300 old questions here? Letting them rest in peace is probably the best.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Why aren't these sorts of questions just moved to the correct site rather than closed as off topic as the defacto action in that case?

Comment: It's complicated. They can be moved, but that has to be initiated by a moderator (and they have thousands of flags / day). Generally, I try to add a comment asking the person to ask their question on Open Source instead - it teaches people about the site, significantly helping the health of the site as well. Even with those comments still, and the amount of on-topic drama there's been, I still find people who fight back *Of course it's on-topic! Are you stupid? You should get out of here!* and stuff like that. People can get fairly hostile...

Comment: Also, about the licensing tags, they shouldn't be used for licensing software, but about incorporating them as part of a software model (such as verifying that the user bought a license to use the program)

Comment: @Zizouz212 It's interesting to hear that side of it. I'm actually impressed by how committed you are to what you do yourself - I've seen your userId around a lot lately! Well done; I'm sure others appreciate it as much as I do!

Comment: @Gui Haha, thanks! I try to help out whenever I can! Also, I like to think that I do a lot of work - if you compare what I do to some of the moderators around here, I almost do nothing :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tag was deprecated as far back as [2012](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5310110/3). The original request to [burninate the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140906/can-we-burninate-the-gpl-tag) was migrated to MSE, but here's the gist of it:

> > Can we burninate the GPL tag?
>
> It turns out that we can't, because it might orphan questions that
> have been tagged this way. **Burninating** removes the tags from the
> system, but doesn't handle the disposition of the questions
> themselves. Something more is needed.
>
> — [CodeGnome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/185951/codegnome)

In other words, it's a slow, painful process. In the meantime, a big fat warning in the tag summary is enough to prevent *new* questions from spawning.

You can try your luck at [Opensource SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) where these types of questions are on-topic. Just remember that nothing on there is legal advice.

Comment: `a big fat warning in the tag summary is enough to prevent new questions` is it though? How many people are reading about the tag before using it? I must confess, I rarely read them myself when asking questions, and I wouldn't expect someone asking an off-topic question to do so.

Comment: @mason With only 50 questions in the last 2 years vs >300 since creation it seems to've helped; either at asking or post ask nuking.  And most/all of the remainder are closed; the problem is that the remainder apparently don't qualify for automatic deletion.

Comment: @DanNeely Those are just the questions you can see. I'm just saying, the warning does nothing to prevent new questions. In the rare case someone checks the tag they might notice the warning and might decide to follow it. It would be much more effective if we could actually mark a tag as deprecated and the system would actually *prevent* that tag from being used.

Comment: Yippie! Open Source! Ask there! Yippie yippie yippie! *Disclaimer: I'm a moderator there :)*

Comment: @mason and anyone who upvoted that comment: you might be interested in [this MSE feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114/997587).