# The [gpl] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I recently encountered the [gpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpl) tag, which has the following description:

> DO NOT USE! LICENSING / LEGAL ADVICE IS OFF TOPIC -- GPL questions should be asked on opensource.stackexchange.com - The GNU General Public License is a copyleft free software license and is the most popular open source license.

I agree - this tag is intrinsically off-topic. There is no valid use case for it on this site - it's simply not possible to write an on-topic question that has this tag.

It gets better, though: *every single question tagged with this is closed*.

That being said, can we just remove this tag entirely? This is essentially no effort cleanup-wise, since everything is closed and just needs to go.

Comment: I know that this is absolutely not the purpose of tags, and I support this request, but it looks like a great honeypot for easily identifiable off-topic posts. Would removing the tag stop people from asking such questions, or would it make it more difficult for us to spot those?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315930/why-arent-relevant-tags-removed-if-a-subject-is-considered-off-topic ...and there has already been a burnination of "legal" tags, where all GPL questions were closed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295218/

Comment: @janw why should we have honeypots of any kind? Better to be upfront and not give any indication, that those questions are accepted here. Keeping tags for that smells like entrapment and it's not fun.

Comment: @Braiam How is it entrapment? The tag description clearly tells you not to use it.

Comment: it looks like anormal used tag, with upvoates and answer, as this has also something to do with programming , i don't see why not

Comment: @PM2Ring Would you be surprised if I told you that [nobody read those?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114/213575)

Comment: @Braiam No. And I realise that it's not easy to make people read things, and the more stuff you shove in front of people, the less likely they are to read any of it, especially if they're relatively new.

Comment: @PM2Ring that's why I said that it's entrapment. There should be not even a little hint that those kind of questions are allowed.

Comment: There is a facility to block a tag, so it can't even be used. This is distinct from deletion – if you delete a tag, someone can always recreate it; if it is blocked, any attempt to ask a question with it or to tag an existing question with it will be rejected by the software. I think that is what should be done with this tag.

Comment: @SimonKissane that facility is only for developers to use, and Ops guys say it it's too expensive.

Comment: This seems reasonable, as is the case with [tag:lgpl]. If someone can sweep through the set of questions, and determine if any of them need a historical lock and share them, I can then try and poke a CM to see if anyone still has the power to mass delete a tag.

Comment: @Braiam I understand that it requires StackExchange staff to do it, it isn't available to SO mods. But how is it "too expensive"? If they already have a list of banned tags, how is it too much work or a performance hit or whatever just to add one more entry to the list? It is just another line in the config file, another row in the database table, however they do it.

Comment: @SimonKissane Bean counter speak: `thanks_emoji_widgets === good_value && UI_fixes !== good_value`

Comment: @SimonKissane don't ask me, ask the Ops. Something something query > 10ns something something.

Comment: Maybe we should request a feature that requires the user to (say) solve a Sudoku before they can use a tag that is labelled "DO NOT USE!".

Comment: I must say, although the questions are very explicitly off topic (for [so]), and most/all have been closed, it also really doesn't help that people also answer the questions, thus validating the OP's question and also future users that search similar problems and see that a similar question has been asked answered (with a marked solution). A different problem, but users contributing to the tag as answerers are only making the "problem" worse.

Comment: @StephenC Or add a feature that just automatically closes questions as off-topic if they include a tag that is labeled as "Do not use." Maybe even include the tag description in the close banner to explain why it's off-topic.

Comment: @Larnu "it also really doesn't help that people also answer the questions" See Braiam above: nobody reads the tag infos, including answerers. To be fair, this has to be seen in historical context. SO was less strict in the past.

Comment: If it stays, the description should be corrected. It may have been true when written, but it is no longer the most popular license.

Comment: @Trilarion Clearly *some* of us do or this topic wouldn't exist. :) But my point is more that someone with a good amount of reputation (or even [600k+ reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39385177/2029983)) *should* know better than to contribute to a completely off topic tag and instead vote to close. Of course, I completely know this to not be true (though I certainly can't *prove* it there are certainly some users that have as much reputation as they do due to answering off topic questions that other votes to close and don't answer).

Comment: Can anyone that made a suggestion to solve this in the comments add an answer with the same text? That way we can vote on them like answers.

Comment: There's also a [licensing] tag which seems equally off-topic.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Post a new burn request then

Comment: +1 for blocking the tag, rather than deleting. If it really is "too expensive" to make a tag blocked, then that is a separate problem that should be addressed elsewhere.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not only are there (as of this post) 333 closed questions and 0 open questions with this tag, there are also another 1201 deleted questions, as can be seen with [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1395201/deleted-gpl-questions).  There *are* some informative posts in there that might have warranted preservation, but they're clearly off-topic (a number of the higher-voted ones would be decent Law.SE posts).

With 1534 problematic posts and zero on-topic posts, it's clear that this tag is attracting a *large* amount of problematic content.  It should be removed so that it stops attracting more.

Comment: "There are some informative posts in there that might have warranted preservation..." They do remain, don't they? Just the tag gets removed from them, or not? Now the question is if we need offtopic closed questions without tags.

Comment: "*It should be removed so that it stops attracting more.*" - I doubt that works. The bad content is still attracted, it just won't be tagged any more :-)

Comment: @Bergi Perhaps!  I can't say for sure.  I could imagine either outcome: either people being totally undeterred, or being deterred by the fact that they can't find any relevant tags (and they can't just ignore the need to add _some_ tag).  It'd be an interesting A/B test to conduct, though probably not worth the trouble it'd be to implement.