# When should we flag for moderator intervention to get a burnination request featured?

Tags: discussion, support, burninate-system, custom-flags

I recently had a [burnination request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406539/can-we-remove-the-off-topic-gpl-tag) that reached a score of 56, and would be low effort for the community. I custom-flagged requesting that it be featured, but it was declined as "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it" with no further explanation.

This left me a little confused as to what to do next, since I don't know exactly why the moderator declined it. What should I have done in this case instead? When are we supposed to flag for moderator intervention for burninate requests?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some burninate requests with over 20 votes not get featured?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356820/why-do-some-burninate-requests-with-over-20-votes-not-get-featured)

Comment: The target Jeanne suggested seems appropriate, but it doesn't explain why your flag was declined. As the answer on the target says, it's probably not useful to flag, but there's no harm in it, if the request meets the necessary criteria.

Comment: @JeanneDark They're related, but my question was more about how we should get them featured in the first place. I'm not sure if the diamond who declined it didn't agree with the request itself or didn't think that I should have flagged in the first place.

Comment: [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/11682469) When there is a large backlog (see the query in the FAQ), you need to be patient.

Comment: @cigien Why would such a flag not be declined? It's not something a mod can do much about (unless they wanted to pass over older burninate requests that may even have a higher score). Declining the flag discourages users from raising flags for that purpose in the future.

Comment: @JeanneDark Sure, that makes sense. However, the answer on the target says "*Yes, users can flag burnination requests that have met the official criteria and that they really want to see get actioned.*" in a footnote. Unless I'm misreading that, that means raising flags is fine, right?

Comment: @cigien While that's true, they are clearly not very much in favor of raising them and also don't claim that such flags would always be marked helpful. Mods also tend to handle flags differently. Also note that already 2 posts are featured on MSO.

Comment: @JeanneDark Hmm, when a mod says "Yes, a flag can be raised", I assume it's implicit that it won't be declined, otherwise the statement is entirely useless :p

Comment: @cigien Some mods say that a declined flag is no big deal and nothing to be worried about (unless you get too many). And marking the flag helpful without featuring the post for 6 to 8 months might also be considered to send out a wrong signal.

Comment: @JeanneDark Yeah, that's all reasonable, but the answer on the target is actively misleading in this regard, IMO. I'll edit it a bit, and I'm sure Cody will make their opinion clear if they disagree.

Comment: Yeah, no. There's no need to flag burnination posts to be featured. I had already given feedback about that particular burnination, which was conveniently ignored.

Comment: I absolutely do not disagree. @cigien's edit is fully in keeping with the tone of the original footnote. Read the rest of it: there should have been nothing in there that would have ever implied that such flags would not be subject to a decline. It's pretty down on the whole idea of raising them. There's a big difference between what you *can* flag and what flags a mod will agree with.