# Synonymize general accessibility tags under one main tag ([accessibility])

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Currently there are three very related accessibility tags:

- The "main" one, [accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accessibility):

  > Accessibility seeks to make an ***application or website*** usable by
  > everyone, including people with disabilities such as visual, auditory,
  > ambulatory, or cognitive impairment.
- [android-accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-accessibility):

  > Adding accessibility to apps increases the app's reach and versatility
- [web-accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-accessibility):

  > Web accessibility is about making web content, including web
  > applications, accessible for people with disabilities and elderly
  > people. This includes compatibility with screen readers and screen
  > magnifiers. Making a web site or web application accessible may
  > include, but is not limited to, making it conform to accessibility
  > standards such as the W3C's Web Content Accessibility Guidelines
  > (WCAG).

I might be completely wrong about this, but it seems to me that the latter two tags doesn't add any important information that is not already given by using the [accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) tag. For example, a question about adding accessibility to an android app is better tagged as [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) [accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) than [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)[android-accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-accessibility)[accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) or any other combination of the three.

My suggestion is to simply make those two tags synonyms for the "main" tag - [accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) (personally I don't have any score there to suggest it).

Some more stats about the tags:

| tag | questions | watchers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) | 6,150 | 1.4k |
| [android-accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-accessibility) | 325 | 44 |
| [web-accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-accessibility) | 217 | 119 |

It is notable that the wiki for [web-accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-accessibility) is a bit more elaborate than the others. In such case that the synonym is done, the wiki from that tag might be merged into the one of [accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) for completeness.

Comment: Regarding android-* tags..... [Fixing the un-prefixed Android tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252394/2821954)

Comment: I think `web-accessibility` should probably stay separate, because there are industry standards specific to web accessibility (like WCAG) which people could be experts in, but which experts in accessibility more generally may not be experts in. Perhaps that's a decent test for whether a more specific accessibility tag should stay - are there industry standards specific to that domain?

Comment: @kaya3 I would go even farther: a tag for the standard itself.

Comment: @Braiam Not sure about that; the purpose of a tag is so that answerers can find questions, in this case the answerers know the relevant standard(s) but the askers might not know *about* the standards. If there is a `web-accessibility` tag then it's more likely to be used by people who don't know about the standards, but whose questions would benefit from answers by experts on those standards.

Comment: @kaya3 that's why we have tag suggestion, so it can kind of make them discoverable. Also, some askers seems to have problem finding [tag:web-accessibility], yet don't have any problem finding [tag:wai-aria] [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68754712/interact-with-buttons-inside-of-an-aria-list-item).

Answer (score 10):

I've been doing a fair amount of work in the area of web accessibility recently, and there is a distinct lack of knowledge around the plethora of standards and how they affect the HTML, browsers, and assistive technologies.

The project I'm on right now is a web app and the phrase used is "ADA compliance" (that is, [Americans with Disabilities Act](https://www.ada.gov/pubs/ada.htm)). The Act actually defers most of the details to [Section 508 of the Rehabilitation Act](https://section508.gov/) and [Section 255 of the Communications Act](https://www.access-board.gov/ict/#255ch1). The necessary adaptations necessary under [section 508 map, more or less, to](https://www.access-board.gov/ict/wcagtofpc.html) those recommended under [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/).

I don't think we need tags for each section of each act of Congress that affects accessibility. Not to mention those of every other country/governing body. That would be exhausting to maintain and given how we try to steer clear of law-related questions (see the fate of [gpl](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406539/215552) and similar license-related questions), off-topic.

I do think, given the breadth and litigious nature of the subject where it touches on web sites especially, that [web-accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-accessibility) should be kept separate at the very least.