# Why is my question about future web censorship closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557683/is-web-censorship-coming-if-so-how-should-web-developers-cope-with-it) about coming [censorship](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-intersect/wp/2015/09/24/the-united-nations-has-a-radical-dangerous-vision-for-the-future-of-the-web/). I, as a web-developer intend to be prepared to that, so I was asking whether it is true, if so, whether there will be a source of information besides reading laws and whether there is a technical way to prevent abuses the said censorship intends to protect users against. The question was downvoted many times and closed as it is opinion-based. However, I was not asking for opinions, but rather for facts. If the facts are unknown, then there is no need to write an answer until the facts will be clear. As about protection against the specific rules of censorship might be broad, but I do not see how is it broad. These rules - if already defined - can be translated into technical rules and if so, then the necessary technical steps can be defined as well.

Comment: This is not only POB, but also off-topic.

Comment: Okay, I will remove both questions and conclude that on SO this question is censored :)

Comment: @LajosArpad the question in offtopic whatever you see as it is not about programming

Comment: @ColdFire, so we do not have to write code to comply to the terms?

Comment: The question isn't censored (if it were, I would have deleted it and never told you to go to meta). People disagree with your view that the question is on-topic on Stack Overflow. And you haven't even waited for answers yet.

Comment: @Kyll, then I will not remove the questions, as the answer is the most important.

Comment: @LajosArpad i said programming not code , the site faq says that is offtopic

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, point taken, did not mean to offend anyone with my sarcastic remark.

Comment: This is one of the most wildly off-topic questions I’ve seen in a long time. It’s a very interesting question, but super duper definitely not for SO. http://quora.com might be an option

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am the original close-voter, and I cast a [cv-pls] review request in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).
First I would like to apologise for the now-deleted comments under your post. As you can see from [here and below](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32920935#32920935), we have a [don't-pile-on](http://socvr.org/faq) rule that was not respected this time.

Here is your main question:

> If websites/apps allowing abuse to women of any kind, what is the definition of abuse, is abuse to men falling into this censorship, is there a way to make sure that this will not be used as a pretext to shut down normal sites and how to comply to them as in, what are the automatic ways or policies which could detect the presence of abuse or even better, forecast potential abuses and what is the way to cope with already existent abuses so that service providers can protect their users against abuse and themselves against censorship?

We can divide it as follows:

1. what is the definition of abuse?
2. is abuse to men falling into this censorship?
3. is there a way to make sure that this will not be used as a pretext to shut down normal sites?
4. and how to comply to them? As in:

- what are the automatic ways or policies which could detect the presence of abuse?
- or even better, forecast potential abuses?

5. what is the way to cope with already existent abuses so that service providers can protect their users against abuse and themselves against censorship?

1 and 2 are purely legal questions. These are off-topics because [we are not lawyers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/4174897) (this answer is about software licensing, however pretty much all legal questions fall under this category. See also the [[legal] burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295117/4174897)).

3 is about the impact a legal policy will have on some category of websites, which really is not answerable by developers. It's also fairly speculative as we'd have to guess the future.

4 and 5 are about how to comply to a policy. While this *could* be on-topic in some way, asking for *ways or policies which could detect the presence of abuse* is simply too broad, as there's dozens of algorithms and strategies and system abstractions and maths papers about this subject.

Do also note that asking multiple questions in one SO question exponentially broadens its scope.

---

Some of your questions may find a better home on our [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/).
I am not familiar with their [rules and culture](https://law.stackexchange.com/help) though. You could ask them [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/24153/the-sidebar).

Comment: I will keep my questions with the sole purpose of keeping your answer, however, unfortunately the real question remains unanswered. I will know the answer in time, but I am not motivated at all to share it, as I can see it will not be received well.

Comment: @Kyll you summed it up perfectly

Comment: Do not worry, I will know the answer in time. Wanted to help people who might not know about the approaching problem, but this place seem to unwelcome the question.

Comment: Maybe revisit with a question / answer pair when you do have the answer.

Comment: @tripleee, I was going to do that, wanted to actually do a research in the subject and if no better answer comes in the meantime, to write the answer to share the info, but given the way my constructive approach was received, I will do this research for myself only.

Comment: I still don't think Stack Overflow is the right forum for this, but that doesn't mean I don't appreciate your information-sharing initiative and effort. We have evolved a fairly specific Question / Answer format which is suitable for many topics, but this doesn't appear to be one of them. Perhaps you should have a blog instead?

Comment: @Kyll FWIW I also close voted the question and headed to SOCVR to ask for cv but you were a bit faster. As far as don't-pile-pn rule, I retracted my dv after I saw question accumulated 12 of them. But maybe it was downvoted so much because it is hugely off-topic question posted by high reputation user that should know better what is on and off topic here.