# Are Visual Studio Licensing questions on-topic or not?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I keep seeing this pop up over and over and I have to shake my head at VS being a constant culprit. Now, we've discussed Licensing before and determined it was off-topic: [Questions about licensing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing)

But then I find this question [Visual Studio Community 2017 is a 30 day trial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390466/visual-studio-community-2017-is-a-30-day-trial)

And this question: [Visual Studio 2017 RC - Prerelease has ended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722168/visual-studio-2017-rc-prerelease-has-ended)

Both are highly upvoted but it seems to violate the rule set forth by Meta. Some would argue, with VS being a programming tool, that it's acceptable. I'm not convinced. Is this a programming tool exception, or a violation of the rules?

Comment: That's not a question about software licensing, it's a question about a development environment. The question is, "My Visual Studio broke; how do I fix it?", which is very different than, "How does license x interact with license y?" or "Which license should I use for my OSS project?"

Comment: The other topic discusses questions *about software licenses*, e.g. *does the GPL protect me from ...* and *what should I use, BSD or MIT*? The questions you found are about a common tool not working. Quite different.

Comment: So if these are on-topic, is there a principle to adhere to? Or is this simply a carve-out for VS that doesn't apply to, say, Windows 10 licensing? I have to ask because someone will eventually make that argument