# Company biased closing of a unwanted question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I recently wanted to link an answer to a question I already answered before. But I couldn't find it. After an intensive search [I found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705697/itext-2-1-7-in-commercial-project), but I realized that is was closed and then deleted. Until now I could mostly understood why answers and questions have been closed (I work on the review queue myself), but this case seems quite biased to me so I raise it here. Some background information:

The topic of the question is about an LGPL licensed library which was stopped by its original author. He basically didn't earn money with it, so he changed the license and started making money with it. Fair play. But additionally since then he actively tries to stop people using that (original) library and uses various methods: Adding comments scaring people with legal consequences, adding sometimes even rude comments telling people to look for a new job, deleting unwanted questions and so on. (I used the standard SO mechanisms like flags, etc. for that...)

The post in question is about 6 years old and has helped various people. But if you look at the close votes they came from him and one of his employees (+ one other moderator which even deleted it afterwards). This is removal of helpful content, biased and a misuse of Stack Overflow for company interests. So how can this question (at least) be undeleted again? Since it is not a high profile question voting for undeletion won't work...

Comment: I know that licensing questions are not ideal however deleting (and not like other cases move it to some other place) causes some aftertaste especially in this case...

Comment: [Licensing questions are explicitly off topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing). Just like any off topic post, licensing questions do not belong on Stack Overflow and are subject to closing and deletion. Sure, they may be useful and good questions, but they are in the wrong place. It's possible that they can be restructred to be on topic for [the Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/), however they have very specific rules for how a question should be asked so make sure to read their how to ask page.

Comment: Can't the question be moved there (to Law Exchange?)

Comment: I'm not an active member of the Law Stack Exchange, and am not sure how they like their questions. You should investigate if the question is on topic there and find out if any parts of it need to be re-written before it can be posted there.

Comment: As much as i'd like to see that answer remain open due to the vitriol i've seen from said user just to spite... the question is in fact off topic, and should be closed and deleted (or at the very least locked) to avoid it being abused.

Comment: @Lonzak You're much better off asking the question in the right place than relying on moderators to migrate it. It's both more efficient and allows your question to get addressed and (if necessary) improved without bouncing around the network. For example, if your question were migrated and then closed on Law, it'd bounce back to the original site, leaving you no chance to edit it to bring it into site standards for that site. If you ask it locally and it's closed, it stays there, you can edit it, and it can be reopened.

Comment: In this case, it's not your question, but the issues are the same. There's no guarantee that the question is a good fit for Law and migrations are generally only recommended in cases where the reception is known to be favorable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got your points and agree with most of them and I did follow Servy's advice :

> find a place where that information is acceptable, and post it there

I checked where those questions could be asked (it wasn't legal although it might have been ok to post it there) and it is:

**[Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/).**

They explicitly allow licensing questions (as long as it has an open source aspect to it of course). As indicated by the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing) of Zizouz212

> [...] and I can tell you that we accept nearly any question that has
>   to do with software licensing. We accept questions that vary from
>   complying with various licenses, and we even allow "license
>   recommendations": recommendation questions that ask the community to
>   recommend a license based on certain criteria.

Now a long time unanswered question got answered for me :-) And isn't that what SO is all about?

Answer (score 16):

Legal questions are very much off topic here.  SO is a site for programming questions, not legal questions.

The post was closed and deleted by a moderator because it's off topic, and doesn't belong here at all.  It's entirely merited.

If you really think that your answer has useful information then *find a place where that information is acceptable*, and post it there.

Comment: Can't the question be moved to Law Exchange?

Comment: @Lonzak Moved where?  And no.

Comment: Except... SO are hypocrits and love to preserve off-topic goo if it yields traffic. [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read).

Comment: @Lundin It's not hypocritical.  The policy is that content that is off topic should be closed, and content that doesn't have significant value to others, and that is unlikely to be improved to be on topic, should be deleted.  That there are some questions that are closed but not deleted (and a very small number that are locked to preserve that status) is all consistent with those policies, which are also consistent with the site's goals.

Comment: @Servy The community and the community elected moderators agree that the post should be deleted, yet SO employees goes against the community decision and undeletes the post. How is that not hypocritical? Assuming that SO the company claims to listen to the community rather than Mammon.

Comment: @Lundin That just means various people have disagreed over how useful the post is.  That doesn't mean that people were undeleting a post *they felt wasn't useful*.   You're going to need to provide some form of citation if you want to argue that Tim doesn't actually think the post is useful when it was undeleted.

Comment: @Servy [Delete the list of random books?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295460/delete-the-list-of-random-books) has currently 71 upvotes, a significant majority as SO meta goes. A well-respected moderator wrote an answer with 73 upvotes where they explain why the post should be deleted, after which they did so - with considerable community backup behind them. After which Tim went in to undo the community decision. The post where he explains why currently sits at score 0, as many upvotes as downvotes.

Comment: @Lundin That just proves my point.  Tim disagrees with you, and others, over the usefulness of the post. That post specifically says that he thinks the post is useful.  You disagree.  You're allowed to disagree.  That doesn't make them hypocritical.  It would be hypocritical if Tim said that he doesn't think it's useful but undeleted it *anyway*.

Comment: @Servy There are rules for what's on-topic. If you violate those rules, your post will get deleted. Except apparently, if your post happens to generate considerable site traffic. Next up is a community wiki with cute cat pictures and porn.

Comment: @Lundin There are rules for what's on topic.  If you violate those rules, your post will **be closed**.  That post *is* closed, because it meets the criteria for closure.  The rule for deletion is that if a post is both unsalvageable, and *not useful in its current state*, then it should be deleted.  A post generating a lot of traffic is a pretty strong sign that it might be useful.

Comment: @Servy Ok so if I create my community wiki about programming-related cute cat pictures, it should be closed but not deleted. And then preserved for the benefit of mankind if a few users disagrees that it should be deleted. Gotcha. Surely this is the route to take to get high-quality programming Q&A.

Comment: @Lundin You're assuming that people are going to agree that your cute cat pictures are useful on this site, which seems reasonably unlikely.  I'll say this for a third time, because apparently you didn't catch on the first two.  If a post is *off topic*, it's closed.  If a post isn't useful, it's deleted.  This means that on occasion a very useful post that's off topic won't be deleted, but will be closed.  Oh, and again, you can disagree with someone over the usefulness of a post, but just because someone disagrees with you over a post's usefulness doesn't make them a hypocrite.

Answer (score 13):

I think there is a certain misconception on your end: questions (and answers) can often be very helpful to many people.

But that does **not** change the rules and policies of the community, about being on/off topic. There are zillions of questions that ask for library recommendations. Sometimes with dozens or hundreds of upvotes on the question, and a gazillion of answers with all kinds of working or broken links. And when I encounter one of those, I put down a close vote.

Yes, it is awkward when questions exist for a long time, and then, after years get deleted. But there is no rule here that says "when content exists for X years, it can't be deleted any more". And such a rule wouldn't make sense.

Comment: "But there is no rule here that says "when content exists for X years, it can't be deleted any more" Imho it does make sense... Maybe not as strict but maybe something like "for each year a question exists and the more votes it has the more closing votes are needed..." or something along those lines

Comment: Regarding my "misconception" - I think SO should put the people first (e.g. helpful posts) and not rules and policies. But you might be right - that is how it is now.

Comment: @Lonzak: SO is in fact putting the people first - the people who count on this being a useful programming resource and not the same as the other noise-and-clutter mess of non-topical garbage. Keeping questions on-topic here preserves the site''s quality. Allowing off-topic questions here dilutes the value of the site, period There's no exception made for *off-topic but highly popular*.

Comment: Valid point. But I would rephrase your last statement to: "_There is no exeption made for off-topic but highly helpful._" Popularity doesn't matter since e.g. some Presidents tweets are highly popular but not very helpful ;-)

Comment: @Lonzak Those who consider said sad tweets popular, they also consider them helpful. But let's not go there. Let's focus on low quality questions, not low quality presidents.