# Request migration to another site if the site isn't in the Close Dialog

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration

I'm aware of the reasons for the [limited amount of migration options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options), but how do we approach questions which should be migrated to another site when the site isn't in the list in the Close Dialog?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662955/cant-do-yum-install-postfix-on-fedora-20) and flagged it as a custom flag for moderator attention:

[image]

I even commented on the question:

[image]

Should we be flagging these type of questions as a custom moderator flag to request migration to an 'unlisted' site?

I fear that my flag is going to be declined with something similar to 'use the close flags to request migration or closure', and as I'm currently close to a ban on flagging (at least I think I am, I was banned from this a couple of days ago), having the flag declined may send me back to a flag-ban.
It's happened before:
[image]

If not, how do we approach this?

Comment: If the migration path isn't in the flag dialog, I doubt mods will decline with "use the right flag". They may decline because it doesn't belong on the target site or is a bad question, however.

Comment: @Kendra Just went through my flags, and turns out it happened before http://puu.sh/cwLZA/acb763a91c.png, but was a straight-out 'we've got no evidence to support this '.

Comment: That's not telling you to use the right flag. It's telling you the mod disagreed with the flag. It was probably a question that either wouldn't fit there, was already asked, or was a bad question to begin with.

Comment: As indicated by @gnat this question has come up (many times) before. My summary of this topic: A migration request is often disputable. It's better to simply flag as _off-topic_ and move on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will sometimes do migrations based on custom flags, but only if certain conditions are met:

- The question must be of sufficient quality (the one you requested to migrate to Super User was not, thus the decline).
- The question must not be on topic on Stack Overflow. On topic, answered questions generally aren't going to get migrated off-site, even if they fit another site.
- The question must not be more than 60 days old. Even moderators cannot migrate those.

Beyond this, we get inundated with these kinds of flags, so moderators generally will decline migration flags from users without a decent amount of reputation on the target site. In most cases, people without accounts on the target site don't really know what is and is not on topic, and we can't possibly keep track of all these sites ourselves. We'll make exceptions for sites that we are familiar with, but that varies from moderator to moderator.

If the question looks decent, the flagger has an account with a good amount of reputation on the target site, and it isn't appropriate for SO, we will migrate flagged questions. We only ask that you flag good questions that meet the above criteria, because we do get piles of these flags and have to deal with them quickly.