# Flag declined, then Question put on hold?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I am a little confused about this, maybe I just understood the system wrong.

A few days ago I came upon this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26730424/1680196

Seeing that this is obviously out of scope for SO I decided to raise a flag, but found Off-Topic as not exactly fitting, as it was still *somewhat* related to programming, but in all the wrong ways.

Thus I went for Needs Moderator Attention, explaining in comment:  `Off-Topic: Requesting to crowdsource HR Q&A work`

This flag was then declined, but the question subsequently put `On-Hold`.

I understand if this is caused by differentiating opinions between whoever declined my flag and whoever put the quesion on hold, but I somewhat expected declined flags to be automatically re-evaluated IF said question actually gets acted on.

Is this a common procedure? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: @psubsee2003 "Tool recommendation" does not feel appropriate for that question, and is not the close reason used by the community either. There is a "blatantly off-topic" reason avalable for flagging only (sadly not for closing), which should have been used here. BTW, I'm shocked that at least 5 people with >3K rep interacted with the question, but only one downvoted it (it's at -2 currently as I added a downvote) - this question is pretty much the definition of "not useful".

Comment: And yet it was put on hold for "opinion based" ...

Comment: @l4mpi sorry... misread his "other" reason that he typed.  You are of course correct

Comment: IMO, that question should have been migrated to meta, so we could give it the answer "No, using the SO voting system to evaluate interview submissions is not welcome".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You asked a *moderator* to put the question on hold. The flag was declined because it doesn't take moderator intervention to close the question.

Just flag the question as [blatantly off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257883/why-do-we-not-have-an-off-topic-flag-for-closing-as-off-topic), it was entirely out-side of the scope of the site, and leave it to the community to deal with it from there. This was not a question about a programming problem, this was a question about hiring, as well as being a polling question, so *Too broad* or *Primarily opinion based* would have fitted just fine too.

The question was put on hold by community vote here.

Comment: Then shouldn't the flag process be a little more dynamic? I went this way because I remembered reading somewhere on Meta that you should go for `other` flag if you don't feel the standard flags sufficiently explain the issue.

Comment: @kasoban: when voting to close (not flagging) there is a free-form option. That's not the same thing as the *Other* option when flagging.

Comment: @kasoban: when flagging, use the 'blatantly' option there, see [Why do we not have an off-topic flag for closing as off-topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257883)

Comment: OK, will do that. Hijacking this for a somewhat related point I remembered when seeing that screenshot: What to choose if I think a question is out of scope for SO, but perfectly on point for another programming related StackExchange which isn't listed it the "belongs to another site in the network" option?

Comment: @kasoban: then 'other' may be appropriate. Migration to sites not in the list is a moderator-only task.

Comment: @kasoban: also see [Flagging migration should include more options](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251652)

Comment: @kasoban - Regarding the migrations, it might be useful to read my answer here as well: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275749/19679