# Yet another flag declined. What should I have done differently?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

So before I start, I have read *[Flag declined, then Question put on hold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276190/flag-declined-then-question-put-on-hold)*, and this is a different matter. Bounties block close votes.

Regarding the question: [node.js readline (or similar) tool to manage a better prompt interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74482240/node-js-readline-or-similar-tool-to-manage-a-better-prompt-interface)

I *flagged* the question when it had a bounty on it, so we could not start a close vote, so only a moderator could close the question at the time I flagged it.

My *flag* message: "I believe this question is deliberately using a bounty to bypass the close vote system because it's asking for a recommendation from a library which is in violation of the rules for questions."

The response I got was "declined - Based on what?"

But based on the fact I read the question,

> I was hoping there is a library that helps manage this so that output
> stays above the input line

This question was asked by a user with >45k rep, 74 gold badges and who has been a member for >13 years. They should know the rules and that asking for suggestions on libraries is a violation of the rules.

So how should I have worked this to explain why I believe it needed a moderator to shut it down? It appears a moderator did shut it down for that exact reason I believed it needed closing for, so I'm not sure what I missed without stating the obvious from the content of the question. I just went with the main topic of why I needed a mod involved. AKA the close vote system locked it because of the bounty.

Comment: *"But based on the fact I read the question, ... "* that explains why you think the question is off topic, what was your basis for thinking the bounty was a conscious attempt to prevent closure?

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine The information about the asker, their Rep and age on the site.

Comment: The user in question has only ever answered 14 questions, while asking 760, you mention their 74 gold badges, but _all_ of them, are question asking related. They have a grand total of 2 reviews (on non-deleted questions), and both were on their own posts, and so they likely aren't into curation. There's every possibility that they _don't_ know the rules associated with bounties.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine the bounty part is a bit different to this a question was that broke one of the most basic rules on the site, you're not allowed to ask a question asking for recommendations point 3 of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, it should and IMHO it is fairly obvious your not supposed to bounty questions like that.

Comment: I understand that, the question is clearly off-topic, but *"deliberately using a bounty to bypass the close vote system"* in your flag is very much debatable.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my last comment Grammarly decided to remove half my message when correcting a mistake.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine There's actually 1180 questions when counting deleted ones, with still only 14 answers

Comment: Generally people who ask more than 100 question are immune to moderation or feedback :) (they can't get automatic bans, and never post content that is against CoC). I would not spend my effort to flag they post is any way (votes, flags, comments, answers) unless a post is outrageously offensive or exceptionally on-topic and not a duplicate...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - How exactly do you know a user with hundreds of questions cannot be question banned? A user who had their low quality questions continuously downvoted and deleted by the community would eventually run into the threshold

Comment: Everyone here seems fixated on the question of malice in using the bounty system. I don't see why; the point remains that an active bounty on the question prevents it from being closed; this one clearly should be closed; and it has been established (and is confirmed in Zoe's answer here) that raising a custom flag in such a situation is appropriate.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You are right, we should not fixate on the possibility of malice. But alas, that happened here and it derailed the flagging process.

Comment: I must say the figures from Nick and Zoe show quite a pattern of something is wrong with this user's behaviour more than 35% of questions have been deleted... wow...

Comment: When you link to a post being discussed on meta, please let the original author know by leaving a comment for them with a link to the meta discussion. I have done so now. This lets them dispute/discuss/learn from the issue, and it explains all the sudden attention and votes their post may be getting.

Comment: @Lundin why the linked question actually has nothing to do with the specifics of this question it's used purely for an example, it's about dealing with bountied questions that are off-topic for the site and need closing.

Comment: @Barkermn01 When you link it here you expose it to "the meta effect", meaning lots of sudden votes in both directions.

Answer (score 9):

I declined the flag.

This is the part I responded to:

> I believe this question is deliberately using a bounty to bypass the close vote system

This is an incredibly bold statement; you're making a claim the bounty is abusive and was placed intentionally and with the sole purpose of evading the closure system. If this was true, at worst, that's worthy of a suspension.

Was the question off-topic? Yes. That's why the bounty was cleared and question closed. You can see that this happened at the time [in the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74482240/revisions)

Are there signs the bounty was abusive, which is the main point in the flag as you wrote it? Not that I can find. Because your flag focused on the abuse and not the need for closure, I declined it. For all I knew, you had some evidence you didn't include in the message because you felt it was obvious, and/or you didn't think to include it in the flag message. That's also a far more frequent occurrence than you might think.

If you see an off-topic question with a bounty, it should indeed be flagged; but don't write a flag message claiming the bounty is abuse with the sole intent of evading closure if you can't back it up. That's also why I replied

> Based on what?

I.e. what evidence do you have the question is "deliberately using a bounty to bypass the close vote system"? It had nothing to do with the off-topicness of the question (which is indisputable; it's clearly off-topic. Again, it got closed at the time), but everything to do with the claim of high-level, active abuse in placing the bounty as a means to avoid closure.

Reputation is also irrelevant here; we have lots of high-rep users who continue to ask poor questions. There are a number of reasons for this that would be worth an entire post on its own, so I'm not going to write one (or attempt to write one) here.

However, a consistent history of low-quality and/or off-topic questions is a separate flag reason. We have a canned mod message for consistently LQ contributions over time, which could very well apply (haven't checked), but even that is far less severe than claiming bounty abuse.

A high-rep user with any asking history asking a LQ or off-topic question and placing a bounty on it is not automatically a sign of intentional bounty abuse. This is regardless of whether that LQ question is business as usual, or a one-off.

Unless there's other indicators, it's either a sign of a consistently LQ asker, or a normally high-quality asker who simply didn't get told that the question is somehow bad prior to the bounty, and for whatever reason didn't notice it themselves. There's a number of reasons for that, but again, worth an entire post on its own.

There's also some people who don't care their question is considered off-topic and post it anyway, but those people overwhelmingly fall into the category of consistent LQ contributors who need a talking-to, and not people who abuse the bounty system to avoid closure.

**TL;DR:** don't flag abuse when you're really flagging for bounty cancellation and closure. Having high rep doesn't mean a bounty is abusive. Consistent LQ contributions are a separate flag reason unrelated to bounty abuse. There's no evidence of bounty abuse from the available information, which is what your flag focused on, and the main reason it was declined.

Comment: Ok, I assumed maybe incorrectly that being in one of the most used tags on the site currently, there would have been a close vote put against it for violation fairly quickly, Also this might need looking at because you state "If this was true, at worst, that's worthy of a suspension", I have just checked a nowhere when applying a bounty does it tell you that, even on the https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty it does not tell you that so I from the information I did not know it was anything more than a nothing, other than a mod had to shut it down.

Comment: "Also this might need looking at because you state "If this was true, at worst, that's worthy of a suspension", I have just checked a nowhere when applying a bounty does it tell you that" - consequences for intentional abuse of specific types isn't listed anywhere in most of the help pages. Take [the upvote page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up); it only mentions that reversals happen, and not that repeated abusive voting is cause for suspension (which it still is, and we do it numerous times daily)

Comment: The general answer that applies to everything is, if you abuse the system repeatedly and it can be proven that it is in fact abuse, there's usually a warning or a suspension waiting shortly after. But the bounty page doesn't need to list that "if you abuse bounties, there's consequences", because that's implied for every part of the site