# What should I do to pass an audit with off-topic questions if there are no standard flag options?

Tags: support, bug, review-queues, flags, declined-flags

I found a question in the First Questions Review Queue that is off-topic for SO, and I tried to flag the question, but there was no flag option except **in need of moderator intervention**. So I chose it and wrote the reason, but why was I declined?

[image]

So, if I get a post that is off-topic/spam/needs details/etc., but have no flag option except **in need of moderator intervention**, should I let it be or skip it?

This is not a duplicate of [Why was my custom flag declined? When should I use a custom flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368693/208273), because that question addresses situations where the other flags are available, which was not the case here.

Comment: Downvote it and leave a comment that is a hell of a change I could live wirhout who ever programmed this not finished in a long shot but I believ this is a dupe

Comment: How about needs improvement > a community specific reason >   
About general computing hardware and software? In the close dialog there is also an "other" option where you can enter a custom text.

Comment: Are you saying that the flag dialog looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkX2X.png)?  That sounds like a bug.

Comment: I have no idea how you were even able to flag [that post](//stackoverflow.com/posts/68940021/timeline).  It was deleted far before you got to it in the [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29764473).  I also tested sending a custom flag on a [review audit of my own](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29770240), and the audit was passed without sending the flag.  I'm also not offered the option to flag the post when I reopen the review.  Of course, I can custom flag it by opening the post itself, but you can't do that without moderator tools (10K) privileges...

Comment: @RyanM could you help to clarify which review queue this (the audit?) was taken from? Or maybe, post the review link here?

Comment: @AndrewT. It's a First Questions review.  I did post [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29764473) (it's on the word "audit" in my previous comment—and was edited in, so you might've loaded the page before it was there), but it's not going to work for any non-10K users other than the OP (since it's their review).

Comment: @RyanM ah yeah, I missed it. Thanks. I could see the review audit and the action that the OP took, and surprisingly(!) the body of the question, the comments, and the close banner. Also, you're right, [this is a (known) bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369109/241919).

Comment: @AndrewT. Oh, that's a very welcome improvement to the system that anyone can see reviews of deleted posts, given a link.

Comment: @AndrewT. Interestingly, though, my custom flag on the review audit was **not** sent, suggesting that maybe this only affects <10K users?

Comment: @BDL there was no option like that, like Ryan M's screenshot

Comment: also possibly related: [Request migration to another site if the site isn't in the Close Dialog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275741/839601)

Comment: @gnat no, my question is not about standard or custom flag, but when no standard flag option.

Comment: absence of migration option in standard list is addressed in the link in my [second comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411343/should-i-let-off-topic-question-if-no-flag-option?noredirect=1#comment866299_411343)

Comment: @gnat yes, second link is related, but this is different.

Comment: it's not just "related" - it's the only thing that is (and should be) available over here. Anything else is outside of meta SO - specifically, you [go to target site meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399732/839601) and discuss things with their community. "I'm coming to a party at your house. What time should I turn up? I've invited all my friends too."

Comment: @gnat To me it doesn't seem like a duplicate. The other question is about when to use custom flags in general, but this question seems to be about what to do if the standard flags are disabled.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because the linked duplicate is about when there **are** other standard flags, which was not the case here.