# Off-topic pull requests to another site

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, scope, migration

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27803554/344286) that really seems off topic. But none of the migration sites were even close, like dba or tex. I'm now aware of [why that is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options) and the options.

> Only off-topic but otherwise high quality questions should be migrated

I wouldn't consider the particular question *high* quality, but it's not exactly a poor question. I would expect that on the Unix & Linux SE it might be a reasonable question. Maybe not amazing, but certainly reasonable.

So I had an idea for a feature similar to the review queues - basically a pull request for questions. Rather than voting for a question to be outright migrated, if we had the ability to say something to the effect of, "This seems like it could belong on their site - hey other community, do you like this question enough to take it?"

That would prevent us just throwing questions over the wall, but would also give another option.

Of course maybe questions like this that aren't particularly outstanding don't really belong on the network at all, in which case that's fine, too. Maybe a "send to Yahoo answers" would be appropriate in that case ;)

Comment: So what's the queue going to do? Decide if this other community should have the question, then what? Or this other community is going to move the question if they want it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure that's a great question; he seems a bit confused about what he's doing, and frankly it's gonna take a bit of work to draw out where the real problem lies. Starting with finding out what shell he *is* using.

If you or the author can provide some clarity to the question, then just flag it for moderator attention, select "other", and type something like "Please migrate to https://unix.stackexchange.com/ - I've fixed it up to be appropriate there." Then close it as off-topic.

Otherwise, close it & leave a comment. Something like,

> This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it concerns a user configuration rather than programming issue. Right now, it's unclear exactly what you're asking, but with suitable details it could be appropriate for [unix.se] - please check out the introduction there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour

As for your feature-request... This is why we're in no hurry to implement such a thing. While your intentions are good, the question as it stands would not be an asset to any site, and migrating it would just create more work for others - even a queue that didn't *actually* migrate would still require work on the part of someone else to review, and if those reviews didn't get done then we'd be no better off than we are now. Better to close it where it stands and offer some helpful guidance to the asker than shuffle it around and add to the existing confusion.