# Off-topic > Belongs on a different site

Tags: discussion, migration

To start off with, this *may* be a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options), but to me, it's only a related topic.

What I want to know is, when I choose to flag a question to migrate, there is a set list of sites to migrate *to* (as described in the above question). However, sometimes the migration options available aren't relevant. For example, a question that (for example) should be migrated to CodeReview, can't be because the option isn't there.

So my question is, (because I've seen it happen before) when does the ability to be able to choose *any* (relevant) site become available? Is it rep? Or is it a mod privilege?

Comment: It's a mod privilege...

Comment: @JonClements is that just because it's too much power to put to a vote?

Comment: Yea, mod only privilege. A non-mod was able to find a way around it  [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251993/possibility-to-migrate-questions-wherever-you-want). @Ben your comment question is answered in the last paragraph of accepted answer on link you provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As moderator Jon Clements ♦ [confirmed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300657/off-topic-belongs-on-a-different-site#comment228026_300657), it's a moderator privilege.

So reputation has nothing to do with it. Get a diamond and you get this ability.