# Triage: more options for Flagging>Closing>Off-Topic>Migration?

Tags: discussion, migration, triage

With a triage review there are only five options when flagging something to close off-topic and migrate it elsewhere:

[image]

What should I do if a question belongs on another site that is not mentioned here, e.g. the WordPress stack exchange?

---

Note: I didn't come across [Flagging migration should include more options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options) because I was looking for "Triage".

Comment: There are only 5 options given in Triage or anywhere to migrate to another site. If you find something that needs to be migrated elsewhere, then you'd select Unsalvageable > In need of Moderator Attention > And explain in detail where it should go.