# Why are the options limited for flagging a question for migration?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration

I have recently come across two questions: [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718003/solving-the-recursion-tn-logtn-11) and [question 2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803837/solve-tn-tn-2-1) Both of these questions are off topic because they don't belong on Stack Overflow. Both are asking similar things about algorithm analysis which would be on topic for [cs.stackexchange.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) For question 1 I left a comment that the question was off topic and belongs on cs.SE. When I found question 2 someone else had already done so and voted to close. Since I'm <3k I can't actually cast a close vote on this question so I thought I'd flag it as off topic. When I navigated through the flag dialogue to the point where I could select which site it belongs on I found that there are only 5 choices:

- meta.SO
- superuser
- tex.SE
- dba.SE
- stats.SE

Is there a reason why we only have these sites as options to flag for closure on a question like this?

Comment: Check out [Flagging migration should include more options](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options?rq=1) as the answer there actually explains this pretty well.