# Do migrations to unix.stackexchange.com warrant it as an option for the Off-Topic Close Question list?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons

Meta devs,

I have read [**Flagging migration should include more options**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options) and understand as of Apr 22 '14 that migration statistics and space are the consideration for not including gamedev.stackexchange.com on the Off-Topic > Close list. Given the age, and the frequency I leave notes on migration to [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) I want to check if the statistics and space constraints may warrant this addition. Additionally, I welcome discussion on whether limiting the list to [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) and [**ServerFault**](http://serverfault.com/) has the effect of skewing the statistics of *Linux* specific questions migrated to **Super User** that would be more appropriate on **Unix & Linux**.

The reason I ask is on the Close Question list of sites, we have **Super User** for general computing hardware/software questions, and we have **ServerFault** for profession server related questions. However, a large number of questions that need to be migrated and closed on S.O. (or just Closed) are *Linux* specific questions, but not professional server related that are more properly asked on **Unix & Linux** (2 out of 3 I voted to close tonight).

I don't know if there is any room to do this, and I get that we cannot put all sites on the list and I agree it should be a statistically determined list, but given the frequency I see **Unix & Linux** question that need to be closed/migrated that are not professional server related questions, I thought I would offer it up for discussion, and if statistically supported, as a feature-request. Especially since limiting the list to **Super User** and **ServerFault** may have a tendency to skew the number of migrations to **Super User** higher when the question would be more appropriate on **Unix & Linux** (if that is by intent, then that's fine).

Just food for thought and a chance to revisit the now 3+ year old most frequently cited basis for the current list.

Comment: Sad to see this without due attention since 2017. I would like to migrate my own question to **Unix & Linux** community, but it isn't listed yet