# No [gaming] on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

*The phase 2 of the burnination process described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) is completed and it has been decided that the tag should be renamed to [game-development].*

---

Currently, the [gaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaming) tag has 376 questions, most of which are relating to the creation of games or creation of game-related plugins/software, etc. I don't see the point in this tag because it conveys no real information. It's overly broad and doesn't give the reader any more information than the title does.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
   Sure, it can be used to describe the contents of the question, but not very effectively. Gaming could relate to creating games, or game-related programs. It doesn't do anything in most cases because the title already provides the information, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795818/puzzle-game-using-c-sharp-windows-form. The title already conveys the fact they're creating a puzzle game, and the question itself is unclear and asking for a debug-pls. The tag encourages bad debug-pls and broad questions with no real use, and itself is broad.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   No. Gaming could be used to categorize questions regarding the creation of games/game-related content, but that has no real need. Gaming itself is off topic for Stack Overflow.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   No.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   It's overly broad and can relate to games, game creation, gamification, etc. Some suited for GameDev.SE and others just plain off topic.

Comment: Oh boy, there are some off topic questions on the gaming tag. Good riddance, I say.

Comment: Notably, such questions might be better off at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Whatever happens to [gaming] should also happen to [game]

Comment: #2:  Writing games is on-topic at stack overflow.   So "No" is wrong; there are things that could fall under "Gaming" that are off-topic, but the same is true of almost every tag you can think of (Java: Talking about the country or coffee is off-topic!)  There is no need to be *wrong* in your answer to the 4 tests just because you want to say "bad tag" in every case.

Comment: I agree about moving them to the gamedev network, is that possible @Lundin ?

Comment: @Zorkind Moderators can migrate posts. But for a successful migration, the moderator also needs to know what's on-topic on the other site.

Comment: So we need to talk to the moderators on gamedev? :-) or are moderators "network wide"?

Comment: I agree with getting rid of that tag.  We do not have a `business applications` tag, so why have a `gaming` tag.  The point is that by virtue of naming an entire class of applications, this tag is general enough that any **good** question on it would just as easily apply to other classes of applications.  By the way, we do have a `scientific-computing` tag, and I wonder if it has the same type of problems.

Comment: @Yakk Agreed. It's just the tag wiki "questions relating to computer gaming" can be interpreted as relating to games in general, not about making or creating games. I can revise if it's necessary.

Comment: So my problem is that there are, or could be, issues that are common based off the *application* of code.  Now, maybe *gaming* is too broad for this?  But someone who is an expert on C++ in gaming may be able to answer a certain silo of questions better than someone who is merely a C++ expert; ie, does this tag (or related "game" tags) help searchability?

Comment: I recently had a problem with detecting facility reservation conflicts in my event management system - as my database grew, my sql query grew way too slow.  I read an article on collision detection for games, and it solved my problem.  I cannot think of a single issue in gaming that would not be applicable to a host of other classes of applications.  To me, that says that the tag, at best, does nothing to help me search for a specific issue.  At worst, it misleads people into thinking that is the tag that will contain the best answers for their issue.

Comment: @Lundin moderators can migrate posts if they're not on-topic here and are on-topic on the target site. However, we can't migrate posts older than 60 days and for gaming that's 378/393 questions - and quite frankly, migration is not the route to go down here. It'd be best to focus on what needs tidying up for them to be suitable for SO instead.

Comment: What is wrong with tagging something as 'gaming'? If you have a question, and it's relevant to game development, then it's totally reasonable for that question to be on StackOverflow and not GameDevelopment.

Comment: @MilesRout I can't think of a situation where a question with an appropriate title and about game development having the tag would make the question better. Gaming, IMO implies the action of *playing* a game, which also doesn't fit right for *developing* games.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring, Q +142/-7

Comment: @Li357 We're out of the "I've got a clever title, vote for me" phase and into the "Let's make sure we want to do this" phase. Comes with a price but the tag will go away in the end.

Comment: @Yakk [gaming] has nothing to do with game creation it is the activity of playing a game which is clearly off-topic to this site. [game-creation] or at least [game] might work. But gaming has nothing to do with programming except the game wants you to program. But then the game itself would be the better tag.

Comment: [gaming] (and also [game] or [game-development]) are too broad. If one has a problem related to game programming it is usually better to tag with the technology the specific problem relates to ([opengl], [directx], [vulkan], [unity3d], [unreal-engine], [physx], ...) than with such a broad tag.

Comment: `[gaming]` is too broad of a tag IMO. `[game-development]` is not overly precise, like a specific technology or framework would be, but I disagree that `[game-development]` is too broad to be a tag. `[game-development]` could be used to ask questions about algorithms or approaches popular in developing games, without asking for a specific language or framework implementation.

Comment: There is also [tag:social-gaming] with only 16 questions.

Comment: It seems like someone was [gaming] the tag system when they created this tag - I say we send it to Trogdor.

Comment: @JonClements Even moderators can't migrate really old questions, though, can they? If we wanted to migrate some older question, wouldn't a CM have to do it? It seems like if we had some really old questions that we can't migrate anymore but are still worth keeping, we should just edit out the tag and either close or historically lock them.

Comment: @EJoshuaS why lock them? If that information can't really stay here, why not simply ask that same question over there? I've done that several times already, and haven't had any problem. *Au contraire*, they were further improved in the target site.

Comment: @Walfrat I'm not sure what you mean - the title *does* reflect the current state, given that it's still being considered for removal. It has to be featured long enough to give anyone who disagrees time to object.

Comment: [gamedev.se] mod here. About the migration: I don't think game development related questions should be off-topic for SO if they're about programming, but encouraging users to ask them on gamedev.se instead of SO in the future (and not on both) might help them get answers more adapted to their context. If SO community and mods feel like they should get rid of game related questions, and that they're on topic on gamedev.se, well sure, in the future, migrate them on a case by case basis, but I don't see the point in migrating all those old questions.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Just FYI, there's a near-0 chance of any migrations, let alone a mass one (most are outside the 60-day window anyways) and [SO mods aren't fond of it either](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251654/2370483)

Comment: @Machavity Yep. So I guess what's left is to educate SO's new users, and tell them that [gamedev.se] is a thing and they would get better answers there :)

Comment: On a personal note, I think this tag's usefulness is to indicate "This question is in the context of making a game, so please steer the answers in that direction.", which is kind of meta, and could be indicated in the question text.

Comment: @AgapwIesu There's one big difference I've noticed between game-related code and business code.  Gaming code often is nondeterministic whereas there is generally one right answer in business code.  (Not always--consider, for example, yield optimization when cutting around defects in wood.  You must make choices with incomplete data and you've got a few seconds for your calculations, you can't get a perfect answer in time.)

Comment: To me it does provide useful information because there is a different program life-cycle to consider. Things the question might not mention but something you have to deduce. There are also other factors that are going to influence the type of answer I write or the added tips / suggestions you might give. Often people copy and paste code trying things and do not fully understand that it was not meant for game code. It might look fine if posted in a normal question, but if you know it is for a game you might steer them in a different direction.

Comment: @BhargavRao The objections notwithstanding, there seems to be consensus around this. Should it advance?

Comment: @EJoshuaS The consensus is towards renaming the tag. I'm inclined to leave it for one more day before taking any action.

Comment: Why do you hate gamers?

Comment: @user234461 When did I say that?

Comment: @LorenPechtel - not sure how the deterministic (or not) nature of a piece of code affects whether "Gaming" is a useful descriptive tag.  Perhaps having "deterministic" and "non-deterministic" as subtags under "algorithm" would be a better move on that front.  Whether an algorithm or piece of code is deterministic or not, that code is sure to not be limited to "Gaming".

Comment: @Chris - if there are life-cycle issues that affect the answer, they should be included in the description.  Just saying that the code is for gaming does not specify anything that would narrow that down.  Give me an example of code that you would use in gaming, or a life-cycle consideration for it, and I can give you a number of non-gaming applications for the exact same code and for the same life-cycle or any other consideration.

Comment: @user234461 - hopefully your comment was in jest.  It is not about hating gamers.  In fact, gaming provides a lot of advancements in software development that are relevant to other areas of application.  It is precisely because of the applicability of any "Gaming" piece of code, to any number of other applications, that "Gaming" adds nothing to the description of the problem.  In the end, getting rid of the "Gaming" tag would be a back-handed compliment to gaming software development.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Non-deterministic makes for big headaches in testing.

Comment: Is it game over for the [gaming] tag?  Come on guys I came here for the pun.

Comment: @Mocking - which means that you are trying to game this comment system.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - very true... but that is true whether the code is to be used for a gaming application or something else.  So the gaming tag tells us nothing.  And, it would be better to use tags that actually tell us whether the code is to be deterministic or not, rather than tell us it is "Gaming" which could be either.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Game code is a big source of non-deterministic code.  I can't recall writing anything else that was non-deterministic in the face of fixed input (don't care about the order isn't non-deterministic, you'll still get the same order each time), but I've done it many, many a time with game related stuff.

Comment: The ratio of the score of this post to the number of questions with the tag seems way too high.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - The list of applications, outside of gaming, for non-deterministic algorithms, in the face of fixed input, is endless.  Think weather prediction, or for that matter, think simulations and modeling applications.  Thompson's construction is a nondeterministic finite automata algorithm for processing regular expressions.  Can you conceive the use of regular expressions in something other than gaming?  Natural language processing can be done with nondeterministic algorithms for advanced pattern matching.  And the list goes on and on and on.  Like I said, endless.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Sure, there are others but they're not what most people deal with.  The main time a typical programmer will see non-deterministic stuff is games.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - there are about 10 million game developers in the world, and about 21 million total developers http://redmonk.com/jgovernor/2017/05/26/just-how-many-darned-developers-are-there-in-the-world-github-is-puzzled/

Comment: Not really a majority.  Percentage of either kind using non-deterministic algorithms, one can only guess.  i think you are judging based on your experience.  I have been in software development for over 20 years and used lots of non-deterministic algorithms and never touched a game professionally.

Answer (score 81):

TL;DR it doesn't seem like an egregious tag to me. I like the above idea of renaming [gaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaming) → [game-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-development).

From the perspective of a person answering questions, I think it makes sense for a game developer to subscribe to this tag. Gaming concepts cross multiple other paradigms – things like buffering, game state, game engines etc.

As noted above, folks in data engineering could find [scientific-computing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scientific-computing) useful.

Not to make too sweeping of a generalization, but if you nuke this tag, then what does it say about any tag that is about a type of problem, but not scoped to a specific language or framework?

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com? The whole problem with gaming is that it attracts questions about making simple games. The addition of the gaming tag adds no information whatsoever. It's just useless. There are better tags.

Comment: @Li357 What's the line between questions in stackoverflow vs gamedev? They're both programming related, so it's a case where I think either would be appropriate. (unlike say boardgames)

Comment: You mentioned game engines and specifically game development (such as implementation detail of game mechanics, etc.) Those are clearly more suited for GameDev since they explicitly relate to games and its aspects. For programming assignments that involve games, such as tic tac toe and chess, etc. the [gaming] tag conveys no information the title doesn't already.

Comment: More suited, sure. But would a post about "the implementation detail of game mechanics" be off topic for stackoverflow? IMO the _question_ is on topic, but there might be more subject matter experts on gamedev. Having more people to answer a question shouldn't affect the tag.


From the perspective of someone answering questions, I look up things by their tag, not title. What are the uses of tags otherwise? SEO?

Comment: Even if everything you said was true, it's more efficient to have one tag for each engine instead of a catch all tag for everything and anything related to gaming.

Comment: @AnilRedshift GameDev did not originally allow programming questions (that were on-topic for SO) on it. That's been relaxed in recent years, but the general rule of thumb is, "Will a **game** developer get me a better answer than a regular developer?"

Comment: As someone in science and engineering, I can assure you that I deplore the existence of a scientific-computing tag.

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work is that **users seldom read the tags**. So we have [gaming], and that must mean we accept questions about general game development, right? It invites users to post off-topic questions ("How do I make this game?"). Then they get frustrated when their question gets closed. Bad user flow.

Comment: @Machavity FWIW a _"How do I make this game?"_ would also be off-topic on gamedev because it's too broad.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt but at least you have a little more resources to figure out what specific guidance would be useful for the OP to improve their post. In our case, at most we would say that it's too broad.

Comment: _What does it say about any tag that is about a type of problem?_ That's a thing I've been pondering for some time. We've been steadily burninating tags that are about problems not directly related to programming. I've asked a question if there are special considerations for burninating such tags [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361739/7296893), but that's gone unanswered. In the context of [this q/a](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366186/7296893), I think we should be restrictive in burninating such tags, focussing on the ones that are actively harmful to the site.

Comment: Disagree. `game-development` is too vague to be a valid tag. Anything can be used for the purpose of game development, so it's a clear meta-tag.

Comment: @AnilRedshift The difference between Stack Overflow and Game Development could be the same as the difference between Sci-fi/Fantasy and Movies; sci-fi and fantasy movies are on topic with either site. It may be the same case here.

Answer (score 37):

As mentioned in the other answer, which the community decided, [gaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaming) has been removed from the system and has been renamed to [game-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-development).

Some stats:

> 360 questions were renamed!
> 1638 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
> 71 tracked tag badges were remapped!

---

## Work left:

We need to cleanup [game-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-development), which can be done by:

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *WITHOUT* removing the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=game-development)

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgame-development%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgame-development%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgame-development%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgame-development%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

Comment: I believe that some coordination could be done if the questions are indeed off topic on SO with gamedev.se. Through I suspect, that it wouldn't be so much content unique to SO.

Answer (score 23):

Often, what is good, sensible or needed in game development is quite perpendicular to what would be considered good in general development.

The most obvious split between gaming development and regular development is that by and large, the development community has settled on the truism that in software development, readability and clean design is widely preferrable over performance, with the exception of obvious edge cases. In contrast, in game development, performance always needs to be on the forefront of your mind when designing anything.

Another common philosophical split is that in general software development, open source is a mindset that is considered the norm and obviously right, whereas games usually need their internal workings to be hidden and obscured lest they make 'gaming the game' too easy.

Due to these contradicting philosophies, I would like to strongly voice my opposition to the burnination. I would support a move like `gaming -> game-development` as suggested by @AnilRedshift if there really is an epidemic of people asking gaming, but not game development related questions, which I personally have not noticed.

Comment: While you raise valid points about the specific needs of gaming software development, none of that seems to be best addressed by a tag. These considerations are best addressed by a clearly-worded question.

Comment: `performance always needs to be on the forefront of your mind when designing anything` I could name a dozen games right now where performance was not an issue in the development of the game. Some games are rather simple in nature

Comment: `performance always needs to be on the forefront of your mind when designing anything.` => *"90% of a program's execution time is spent in only 10% of its code. The standard inference from this rule is that programmers should find that 10% of the code and optimize it ... But a second inference is just as important: programmers can deoptimize the other 90% of the code (in order to make it easier to use, maintain, etc.)" -- Richard Pattis* (cc: @LonelyNeuron)

Comment: I would rather put the distinction that regular development is all about reuse and building upon the existing solutions, while games, however masterful, are always a one-off product.

Answer (score 4):

Good, on-topic questions that are related to game development should just be retagged [game-development]. Game development is an actual programming topic that you can legitimately be an expert in (in fact, they offered entire courses in game design and development when I was in college). The rest of the questions can either be closed and deleted or can do without this tag completely - the tag isn't contributing anything of substance to them.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   Yes, it describes the contents of questions to which it is applied; they are almost universally problems about programming games. It is pretty unambiguous that what programs are games.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Programming games is quite clearly on-topic for this site.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   Yes. Gaming in general has a different set of requirements than other kinds of programming. To be concrete, there is a significant difference between the assumptions that the C++ gaming ecosystem and general C++ programming has, about as large as the difference between embedded C++ or other domains.

   Experts in C++ gaming programming will be aware of common assumptions in C++ game programming: exceptions are often disabled, RTTI is gone, std library is often replaced (sometimes with behave-alike libraries with different performance characteristics), etc. And the kind of APIs you are going to use and how you'll solve them on various platforms will differ if you are writing a game.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Yes, it means writing programs for games. How that changes the meaning of the question will vary with other tags; a C++ question with gaming is going to be different than a PHP question with a gaming tag, but both are going to be about making a program that is a game.

---

The OP *forced* the answer to no in all of the categories in question. I'm not stating it is a *great* tag, but burnination and mass removal in theory is supposed to require a horrible tag.

Comment: From the [meta tag post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) `The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question. They describe some other aspect of the question` [gaming] is essentially a meta tag. While it describes an *overall goal*, it is not essential to the question. Indeed, in many of the instances its used *it's never even a main part of the question*. In fact, most of the questions are vastly disparate and [some are little more than "this is for a game"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45907185)

Comment: @Machavity The fact a tag can be used incorrectly is not a reason to burniate.  It isn't *essentially* a meta tag, it can be used as a meta tag.  And things that can be used as X are not *essentially* X.

Comment: "but burnination and mass removal in theory is supposed to require a horrible tag." I was under the impression that it was a not useful tag instead.

Comment: Yakk, while it may be that large swaths of games have certain things in common, those things do not come from their game nature.  A spaceship combat game has similar constraints to a flight simulator (which is not a game) and very little in common with a poker game.

Comment: Disagree with (3). Rather add more tags, which specify engine/library/whatever. E.g. tag `[unity]` tells more about the question than `[gaming]` in that aspect. When those are specified - `[gaming]` adds **nothing**.

Comment: @Sinatr The existence of a situation where a tag is redundant does not mean that the tag never adds meaningful information to a post?

Comment: @Yakk, it's not like this. `[gaming]` alone only tells "the guy forgot tags", nothing more. *"problems about programming games"* - which problems? Maybe [tag:path-finding] or [tag:sprite], or [tag:artificial-intelligence], or [tag:artificial-life], or some other, which already **has tag**? So why using `[gaming]` and not **proper** tag? To ask broad question?

Comment: Whenever you search for solution, would you use `[gaming]` tag **at all**? Nope, you will try to use more specific tag/word, because, while you may be writing a game, you wouldn't mind to read about solution applied to not a game. To me tagging question with `[gaming]` is like tagging with [tag:design] when you are making some designer software. It's wrong and not helpful. Read this: "but I am doing program for design, it's not the same as other programs and has its specific problems and goals"..

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, what would happen here is that someone who tried to tag their post [game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game) or [gaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaming) would be offered the choice to:

- Post their question on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/,
- Retag with the specific engine (e.g. [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d)) they have a question about, OR
- Ask the question as an algorithm question ("how do I check the state of multiple objects (who cares that they happen to be enemies in a game) and have them update themselves?" rather than "I want to make a game like this, but I want you to do it for me.")