# Can we have some clarity for [online-learning]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I recently came upon [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27191871) for the tag-wiki for [online-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/online-learning) and was somewhat confused (I skipped the review, BTW). Now, although this ***is*** a reasonable (even good) summary of the [*machine online learning* technique/algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning), I was somewhat confused by it.

To me (and others in chat), "online learning" more naturally applies to sites like [Moodle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moodle) (and even those frequent "enemies" like [CodeChef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeChef) and others, which cause so many strange posts here on Stack Overflow).

This isn't really a "burninate" request - just a discussion, and looking for possible suggestions as to how to disambiguate the tag usage. There are currently only 11 questions with the tag, so it's probably not a major issue (yet); most of those 11 questions seem to take the "machine learning algorithm" meaning.

---

For those who cannot see the suggested edit, here is a transcript:

> Online learning is different than other approaches, such as batch
> learning techniques, which generate the best predictor by learning on
> the entire training data set at once.
>
> It is a common technique used in areas of machine learning, where it
> is computationally infeasible to train over the entire dataset,
> requiring the need of out-of-core algorithms.
>
> It is also used when it is necessary for the algorithm to dynamically
> adapt to new patterns in data, or when the data itself is generated as
> a function of time, such as "stock price prediction" for example.
>
> In scikit-learn for example, the SGDClassifier features an
> implementation of online learning.
> [Reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html)

Comment: I don't see why we need a tag for another technique about ML, also I don't see how it's on topic, if it's not about a library, for which a tag must already exist.

Comment: @Braiam Well, you've raised some extra concerns; and *valid* ones. But online-learning may or may not be a useful tag (in the "Moodle" sense), especially with more teaching institutions using it because of COVID. (Not that I'm saying it would be on-topic, though.)

Comment: Well ... moodle and openLM for instance both offer APIs, questions pertaining to either might be perfectly valid for the tag.  Of course that begs the question whether tags per product would be more reasonable ...

Comment: EWWW... a tag for online learning platforms? Nope. Didn't we learn [time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255169/792066) and [time again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360795/792066) that tags work best when they are about a specific concrete tool, rather than mixed bags.

Comment: @Braiam You mean, you want to burn "arrays"?

Comment: @Scratte And then a Bonfire of the Vectors?

Comment: I'm more curious about the history of this tag since [the (currently) oldest question already has this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60860178/1) even though the OP doesn't have enough rep to [create a new tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)... that means, there were more questions with this tag that have been deleted/roomba'd...

Comment: ... or, well, a more probable case: the tag has been removed from older questions after the current oldest question was posted...

Comment: @Scratte Why would we need an online-learning tag? I imagine any question tagged with that would be seeking advice on which course to take to learn how to program. Questions like that are unneeded. I agree tags such as arrays, and vectors, are fine, but this specific tag needs work to become on-topic.

Comment: @10Rep I'm not saying it should be there. I do not know about machine-learning and whether there is a good reason to have this especially for one type of machine-learning. I just noticed the "mixed bags" for which a lot of tags fit, among them "arrays". But.. about abusing tags, I've seen a multitude of different ways to abuse them, not limited to adding irrelevant tags just to get more attention to a post.

Comment: @Braiam Not agreeing is not inherently un-constructive. I've read the post, and I do not agree with it. And.. I do not agree with your argument for why the tag should go. I believe that the right reason to burninate it is the important factor when making a decision. (I do find that telling me to basically "go away" is very un-constructive though)

Comment: Java is an island of Indonesia, yet we do not have a problem with the Java tag. Because the island is utterly off-topic. Just as questions pertaining to the use of online-learning platforms like Moodle would be. As such, I don't see the problem with the online-learning tag. Its appropriate for the concept the tag wiki describes, just like the Java tag, despite Java also being an off-topic island.

Comment: @Polygnome - there is an important difference: we do not have a problem with questions about Java the island (or one of the states, or cigarettes for that matter), and we *do* have one about online learning platforms, that's why folks are so jumpy about any tag name that may suggest to the ignorant that asking about platforms is ok here. If Java wasn't so popular, and we got a slew of questions about how many cups of coffee one needs to stay productive, the tag would quickly end up in disambiguation requests. Anyways, as I mentioned in the answer, the tag is salvageable in more than one way

Comment: @OlegValter Is there any way to actually quantify the problem? The question here was asked not because of many poor questions with the tag, but because a tag wiki edit was reviewed. It feels like this is an issue not actually existing at the moment.

Comment: @Polygnome - 1 / 11 askers thinking it is about "Learning Content Providers" seems like a bad enough stat to warrant a discussion on the tag, Adrian did the proper thing in my opinion - brought it there before the tag became a problem ( and it is easily fixed - btw, can someone with enough rep to do so approve or improve the pending edit? I think it is a good enough one )

Comment: @tink for that we have [tag:moddle] and [tag:openml]. Why have two tags for the same thing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Proposal**

To remove the ambiguity from the tag, it is proposed to:

1. Define a tag wiki for the tag that will unambiguously describe it as a machine-learning technique (as the suggested edit does) and not a tag about learning from online tutorials<sup>0</sup>.
2. Choose between one of the three alternatives:

   1. [online-learning-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/online-learning-algorithm), which follows [an established](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1263219/tags-and-their-wikis-and-excerpts-that-are-similar-to-tag-name?tag=algorithm&starts=0) `*-algorithm` pattern
   2. [online-machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/online-machine-learning), although `*-machine-learning` [is not](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1263219/tags-and-their-wikis-and-excerpts-that-are-similar-to-tag-name?tag=machine-learning&starts=0) an established pattern<sup>1</sup>
   3. Prefix with `ml-*` to make it explicit for those who do not read wikis (which are likely to be the ones who ask about online learning platforms)<sup>2</sup>.

**Tag stats**

There are only [6 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/online-learning%2B-scikit-learn?tab=Newest) that are tagged with [online-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/online-learning) which do not have [scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scikit-learn), of which only one is off-topic and already closed ready to be roomba'd, so there is little to no ambiguity to the tag *per se*.

---

<sup>0</sup> The suggested edit (and tag excerpt) can be expanded with usage guidance, something along the lines of "Use for questions about machine learning, not online learning platforms". 
<sup>1</sup> A search query for "Online Machine Learning" also [yields relevant](https://www.google.com/search?q=online%20machine%20learning) results. 
<sup>2</sup> Note that this is not a proposal to introduce a pattern of hyphenation to [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning).

Comment: I've accepted your answer because: (a) it is a good analysis of the situation; and (b) because you have made some sensible proposals (I prefer the first). However, I feel that none of the proposal will turn out to be especially popular, unfortunately.

Comment: @AdrianMole - thank you, I hope at least one of them makes it - it seems to me like there is no appart issue with the tag as is, just needs some care to fit in (happy to provide one if there are no dissenting voices for a while).

Comment: And thanks for the edit, btw (my god, that was an embarrassing mistake)

Comment: My gripe with [online-learning-algorithm] is that it sounds like a cousin of [seo] (because search engines are basically that). I'd lean more towards [online-machine-learning], since that's easier to understand, even if it's an anti-pattern

Comment: Or we can just remove the non-scikit questions and synonym (even easier)

Comment: @Machavity - if the second proposal sounds good to you, then I can get behind it ( although I believe that the more correct naming would be to suffix the tag with `*-algorithm`, the group of online methods constituting online learning seems to be commonly referred to as "online machine learning", so we would be in line with common usage and thus pragmatically correct ). If there are no objections, can you go ahead and make the change? Thank you!

Comment: [tag:online-machine-learning] would at least be the same as the Wikipedia entry for the same topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning. Thats not a bad property to have in terms of discovery.

Comment: @Polygnome - agreed, probably this will be the most practical option (although online learning is more of an umbrella term, and not usually referred to directly [ironically, except for wikipedia]) in terms of visibility.

Comment: Done. Tag renamed. Could use a proper excerpt tho, if anyone wants to chip in there

Comment: @Machavity, yay, thank you! Re:excerpt - can look into a bit later if no one beats me to it.