# Allow users with sufficient destination site reputation more migration options

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, migration

[@Davidmh](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3375011/davidmh)'s suggestion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268005/765226)  would allow for more migration options while mitigating the problem of things being migrated when they shouldn't be.

The idea is that if a user has sufficient reputation on the destination site (to ensure they know what actually belongs there) then they be allowed to flag for migration to that site. For example, I have several thousand reputation on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) so I would be allowed to flag Stack Overflow questions for migration to there, but not to a community where I have little to no reputation.

There was a definite interest in this idea, so I'm posting this question to be discussed separately. See also:

[Better "Flag for migration" interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210545/better-flag-for-migration-interface)

[More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

[When voting to migrate an off-topic question, why is the list of sites limited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited)

Comment: The number of migration options should be the same for all users, (except the OP) - none.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: ["List of migration sites should be dynamic, based on reputation at destination"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147804/list-of-migration-sites-should-be-dynamic-based-on-reputation-at-destination), although that was aimed at further restricting the options, not expanding them.