# The flag menu nesting is too deep

Tags: discussion, flags, user-experience

When a question as "off-topic because it belongs to another site which is stats.stackexchange.com", then you need to choose `flag->should be closed->off topic->belongs to another site->stats.stackexchange.com` which is four clicks until the actual option you're looking for is shown.

Especially the `off topic because ...` option does not convey in a good way that it has a submenu which i.e. contains `move to another site`. Of course it logically belongs there somehow but in the menu flow it still seems counter intuitive.

I was surprised that I need to click `should be closed` to request a question to be moved to another site and in the past used `moderator intervention` because it was not obvious that there actually *is* a menu option to request a move.

I would like the options with submenus to have a more clear indication that they have a submenu. A radio button indicates that you can choose this option, not that the menu is replaced by a submenu with new radio buttons. Using a button for options which open a submenu would be an alternative or just adding some visual indicator (maybe a little arrow?) to the option. I guess https://ux.stackexchange.com/ can help with some advice on how optimize the flow.

Another minor issue: I think it is counter intuitive to have superuser/serverfault options separate from the list which i.e. contains stats.stackexchange.com. And while the list of further sites like this contains the icons of the network sites, the option to move to server fault or super user has the site name at the end of a whole paragraph of text without any icon.

I think as a solution the structure of the menu should be more flat and possibly the options should have less text and be more precise in what the flag is. I.e. a option `move to another stackexchange site` in the first menu and then a list of stackexchange sites would be an huge improvement.

On the remark to migration: Hiding it may be an idea to avoid too many migration requests, but as questions often have a prominent banner "migrated from" you know there is this flag and then it is hard to find.

To avoid the discussion being too restricted on the example: Requesting migration is the option where you find the deepest nesting, but many of the other options are not obvious enough as well.

And personally I think many of the options have a TL;DR amount of description text. Reducing it from one paragraph to one line would be helpful as well and speed up deciding "oh, I need to use the submenu at this option". But this might be a controversial topic how much text is needed there.

Comment: Migrating is very often not a good idea. It's not put front and center as to prevent encouraging users to flag for migration things that we should be closing/deleting instead of migrating.

Answer (score 4):

Migration is both hard and VERY limited. The main reason why is that migration is often not a good choice for the recipient site. From [Martjin's explanation on why we don't have more migration options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251654/2370483)

> The problem with allowing arbitrary sites to be entered is that a lot of the time, the community on one site has *really no idea* what is on-topic and considered of sufficient quality on another site. As such the Stack Exchange dev team has resisted adding a open-ended migrate option; the Stack Overflow community doesn't get to decide what is on topic in other communities, basically.

In other words, the menu is buried for a reason.

If a question is off-topic on SO, you should vote to close it with a custom reason that suggests posting it on another site. If the OP decides to ask for a migration, they can mod flag for it. I can count on one hand the number of times where I felt confidant enough to mod flag someone else's question for migration and have it happen. Migration should not be the first choice in 99.9999% of closures.

Comment: I think the other options would benefit from more clarity as well. As in the updated question, migration is one prominent example, but there are more. I think there should be more visual indication that an option has an submenu as well.

Comment: @allo, the ellipsis (...) is a well known indicator of "this menu option has more to choose inside".

Comment: Yep. But it is not very visible in the menu. Some clear indicator would be good. And a radio button is an indicator for a choice, not for opening a submenu.

Comment: @allo Well it's really a form where you're picking one of at most seven options.