# Where is the decision line for migrating questions that seem primarily statistics related?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, migration

Three of us made statistics-related comments to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62762662/developing-an-equation-describing-variables-relations-in-r

The first comment links to a post on Cross Validated, which answers the question.

I reviewed the question, identifying it as one that should be migrated to Cross Validation (under "not suitable for this site"). The site linked in the first comment.

The flag was declined.

Where is the line between something not being suitable for the site because it's asking a question about output that is software-independent (every piece of software that does that analysis will give the same output), versus it being a programming question?

I'm scratching my head over why this flag was declined, and would appreciate answers/comments.

Edit: Here is another recent one where I suggested migration, and the post flag is disputed: [can we use 'standard error of sample' to know within which standard error the population mean lies from the sample statistic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823449/can-we-use-standard-error-of-sample-to-know-within-which-standard-error-the-po) Confidence intervals and standard errors fall under the ambit of statistics, not programming. Again, I'm at a loss as to why this is disputed - although the flag being disputed instead of simply declined is perhaps progress, from my perspective.

Comment: "ask if it could be appropriate and on-topic for you, the experts who the author decided to ask. **Be a bit jealous of your site** – don’t blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else. Don’t hit them over the head with your scope, help them tailor their question to fit into it – and if that means your site’s scope overlaps a bit with another site’s, so be it..." ([Respect the community – your own, and others’](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/22/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/))

Comment: The example they gave meant that the lm output was printed directly to console. This is similar output to other statistics packages: http://www.learnbymarketing.com/tutorials/linear-regression-in-r/, https://www.spss-tutorials.com/linear-regression-in-spss-example/, and not stats packages https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/062215/how-can-i-run-linear-and-multiple-regressions-excel.asp

Answer (score 10):

There's a couple of points here

1. Don't assume a mod knows enough to make that call. [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) questions are on-topic and there's no easy way to see if the question is off-topic without knowledge in that domain. From my layman's view, it appears to have a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which is the most common reason it would be off-topic.
2. The other site has different rules and [mods are loathe to migrate for that reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251654/2370483)

   > The problem with allowing arbitrary sites to be entered is that a lot of the time, the community on one site has really no idea what is on-topic and considered of sufficient quality on another site. As such the Stack Exchange dev team has resisted adding a open-ended migrate option; the Stack Overflow community doesn't get to decide what is on topic in other communities, basically.

## What's the standard?

From Martjin's answer

> Most of such questions are not actually off-topic on Stack Overflow. Sure, they may be on-topic on [that other site] as well but that is no reason to migrate a question.

In other words, the question must be

1. Clearly off-topic here (not clear in this case)
2. Clearly good enough to move over there (also not clear in this case)

In most cases, what I would do is flag for closure with a custom reason explaining why it's off-topic here (the [help center page is handy here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Or, if that's too much work, just leave a comment to that effect. Migration requests are more likely to be successful if you can **get the poster to ask the mods for it directly**.

I should also note that there is a direct migration path for close voters to migrate it themselves. If you reach the 3k privilege level, you can cast those votes yourself. 3 votes and it moves. Just be prepared that it might be rejected.

Comment: This is a great answer. However, can you please update to clarify that, in this specific case, the flag was not declined by a moderator, but rather by [three of their peers voting to leave the question open](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/26605142)?

Comment: As someone with domain knowledge, it's very unclear and nearly certainly lacks an MRE (unless I misread the question and it's only _how do I extract the equation from a linear model_, but then it also would not be minimal since that's a very basic question). We lack the data, and what kind of "relation" should be described (unless it's really just the linear effects without interaction). As the comments under the question hint at, this likely is an X-Y problem, and the statistical approach is wrong altogether, but that doesn't make a good question for Stats.SE.