# Migrate or close low- or medium-quality questions?

Tags: discussion, migration

I frequently come across questions that (1) are medium- to low-quality and (2) clearly belong on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) (CV). (They're not completely hopeless questions, i.e. I think *could* be salvaged and turned it to useful CV questions, but they need some work.) I'm always torn about what to do about them (i.e., what close reason to supply):

- if I vote to close as low-quality, it might get improved and re-opened on SO, but then it will still need to be closed/migrated to CV because it's off-topic
- it feels wrong to close/migrate to CV, because that will just saddle the CV community with a low-quality question to improve.

What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Don't migrate poor questions. Just close them. You can use custom close reason stating they don't belong on SO at all. If the question is improved on SO, but it is still off-topic then chances it will be reopened here are slim.

Comment: The general migration guidance is to only migrate questions of exceptionally high quality. There's a few ways that's phrased (read: various degrees of how strict the migration criteria are), but the general rule is that we don't migrate garbage. Most things _can_ be salvaged. Few things _get_ salvaged. Also, while not necessarily about Cross Validated, some sites hate migrations. Notably, Code Review has a bot that detects mentions of Code Review, and regularly tell people off for vaguely posting what may be a hint at the existence of CR (... mildly over-dramatized, but you get the point)

Comment: The point  being, if it's trash, we handle it where it's posted. That applies network-wide. The general guidance is to not migrate unless it's clear it's on-topic on the destination site. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399199/6296561

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine, thanks. (For your second point: as a fairly active participant on CrossValidated, I  would say that sensible SO → CV migrations are fine with people there ...)

Comment: Just for the record, my second point wasn't targeted at CV specifically. Migrations are periodically a point of frustration for other sites, largely because they're under-"staffed" to deal with any volume increase if SO actively redirects questions. Notably, softwarerecs struggled to keep up back when the question wizard redirected some users there. I digress; it's more an answer to migrations in general. Both the points you list are reasons why. Worth noting that the first point may not happen. Sufficiently off-topic questions are going to stay closed, even if they're improved (1/2)

Comment: to the point where it's considered high-quality on a site where it's on-topic. in those cases, a migration can be done by a mod, but I'm not gonna lie, I haven't seen any cases like that yet. Questions unsuitable for migration tend to stay unsuitable for migration, in my experience

Comment: Perhaps the judgement of a nature of question, depends what its asking about? 

If a  question if about an obscure subject its only attract a very low single to noise ratio.  If the question is about a well know subject, everybody will know the answer, hence there should be a lot of high quality answers

Comment: When i see a question that is low quality: i try to edit it as quickly as possible, to make it higher quality, before some unhelpful, mean-spirited SO user tries to close it. I try to make SO better. This runs directly counter to some SO users who have said, *"It's not our responsibility to make StackOverflow better."*  He's right, it's not our responsibility: it's our privilege.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should never migrate low- or medium-quality questions. It's highly likely that they'll get closed on the target site. This is incredibly discouraging for the poster.

Instead close on Stack Overflow and encourage the poster to ask a better question on the target site. Even if the poster improves the question on Stack Overflow it won't get reopened because it's off topic. The only thing that would possibly help here is the ability to migrate closed questions, but the number of times this would happen is so small it's not worth the effort to develop the feature.

In fact I'd go as far as saying that even what you think is a good quality off-topic question shouldn't be migrated. You might not be 100% up to date with what the potential target site wants and so could end up causing the poster to have an even worse experience.

Comment: Fair enough. Again, as far as the last paragraph goes, I am active on both sites, so I don't think that's a concern.

Comment: @BenBolker - unfortunately that's not the case for a lot of people so it's always better to err on the side of caution.

Answer (score 0):

Low-quality questions are still low-quality if migrated to another site.

My usual rule of thumb is that I only vote to migrate questions that I'd be willing to upvote if they were posted on the target site. Otherwise, you should downvote and/or vote to close.