# Should Information Security be added to flagging options?

Tags: discussion, flags, site-recommendation

When you flag a question for the community-specific reason, "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network", there is no option to select the [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange. These are the only options:

[image: Current list of options]

Server Fault is also available as an option elsewhere in the flagging menus. But it seems to me that [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) should be an option also. I often find questions that are better suited for that site and it would be good to have an option for that so those questions can be more quickly given an appropriate flag.

I understand that requests to add more options when flagging for migration have not been well-received, historically:

- [Flagging migration should include more options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251652/4376309)
- [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96205/290054)
- [When voting to migrate an off-topic question, why is the list of sites limited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79960/290054)
- [Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77264/290054)

But I've noticed that IT-related questions that are not about programming seem to come up often enough to make inclusion on the list above helpful. Has anyone else noticed a high frequency of migration-suited questions that belong on the [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site? Maybe there is data on this but I don't have access to it.

Comment: Well, mods cannot add/remove arbitrary sites to the migration target list and thus this needs CM to modify, and they need proof that it's worth the change. Unless questions that should be migrated to [security.se] are high on the list, this feature won't pass.

Comment: @AndrewT. Is there a way to determine that? Without any data we are pretty much guessing in the dark. I notice a high proportion of such questions in my own activities, but I wonder if there is better way of knowing how many posts get migrated over to Information Security. Maybe there is data on this but I don't have access to it.

Comment: Not common enough IMO

Comment: It's at the max already, I believe... you'd have to say one should be dropped.

Comment: @Catija How common are migrations happening for the [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) option? Seems like that one doesn't come up much; could it be a candidate for being replaced with Information Security? I wonder what the stats are for migrations of these types. Keeping in mind that migrations for Information Security would likely happen more often if there was an option for it on the flag menu.

Comment: I've yet to see C# question that would deserve migration to the "information security" site... There likely other tags where it is more common - some more precise data than "noticed" (at least dozen of last week examples should be easy to come by based on the post). So far I see zero reasons why this is a good suggestion.

Comment: Over the last 90 days we have migrated a sum total of zero posts to InfoSec. There is absolutely no point in adding this to the list and bump off another site from our 5 slots.

Comment: But in the last 60 days the community also migrated 0 questions to Tex: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1300198 (2nd resultset). If something is to change we at least got the candidate that can go.

Comment: @rene your information is incomplete. There have been 11 migrations in the past 90 days. None were rejected even.

Comment: @MartijnPieters bah, mods and their fancy tools ;)

Comment: @rene I think your query is hampered by the fact that migrated posts are deleted on the original site. Your numbers are definitely off for all target sites that I checked.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Relations involving deleted posts are no longer kept in SEDE. I thought the migration  stub was kept for 60 days as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters & rene, thanks for looking into this. I concur with your sentiment now that more info is known :)  I've been doing a lot of flagging recently and came across a number of questions that seemed fit for Information Security and part of what stopped me from acting on them was the lack of a specific option for migrating to Information Security. If I find any in the future I'll use the "Other" option for mod intervention. Good to know that my sampling is not necessarily typical.

Comment: @peacetype: before you do make sure you have read the [FAQ on migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work), especially the *When should I consider migration, and when is it inappropriate?* section.

Comment: @rene it's a 10k tool... https://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments under my question, Martijn Pieters says:

> Over the last 90 days we have migrated a sum total of zero posts to InfoSec. There is absolutely no point in adding this to the list and bump off another site from our 5 slots.

I don't have access to that data, so I appreciate Martijn looking up that info. It sounds like adding this option would not be the right move at this time.