# How should I have flagged this Vim-centric question?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, declined-flags, migration

When I flagged [this Vim-centric question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64268666/5825294), I chose *in need of moderator intervention* and wrote

> This question is not about programming at all, but purely about vi/Vim, furthermore it provides plenty of useless details, which can only mislead the reader. Therefore, I've re-crafted it and asked on vi.stackexchange, vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27601/…, also providing a screencast that demos it. I think this question could be closed or removed.

I did so by referring to [Flagging migration should include more options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options), and its [accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251654/5825294), which reads:

> you can flag such a post with the 'other' option and an explanation why the post should be migrated; a moderator will handle the migration in that case

The flag has been rejected with comment

> declined - If it is off topic here then use the standard flags to vote to close it.

I suspect one of the reasons is that probably there's no need to move the question anymore, since I have re-asket it myself on the target site.

Is this the case? If no, then I would I apply the moderator's suggestion? How should have I flagged the question?

Comment: VI and VIM is on-topic. Programming tools/ide's are on-topic. They shouldn't be closed, nor migrated if asked here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your flag was not asking for a migration. You asked for the question to be closed and deleted.

Your flag read, in full:

> This question is not about programming at all, but purely about vi/Vim, furthermore it provides plenty of useless details, which can only mislead the reader. Therefore, I've re-crafted it and asked on vi.stackexchange, vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27601/…, also providing a screencast that demos it. **I think this question could be closed or removed.**

I declined your flag because moderators do not need to intervene in the normal processes of closing and deleting questions here.

Note that questions about tools commonly used by programmers are **not off-topic** on Stack Overflow. The existence of a dedicated ViM Stack Exchange doesn’t make such questions on Stack Overflow off topic. It could be the question is off topic for other reasons (too broad or lacking details, etc), but the community can handle closing posts for those reasons directly.

And while it is great that you managed to create a better version of the question over on ViM.SE, the existence of that post doesn’t make this post on SO off topic or in need of deleting.

Comment: Plus, once I created the (improved) question on vi&Vim, then I could technically flagging that question as duplicate. But cross site duplicate are not available. However, ok, I'll accept there are unflaggable questions.

Comment: For who knows which reason I though that also the _other_ was bothering you mods. Thanks for explaining the difference.