# Is a pure combinatorics question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64317428/5825294) question off-topic?

I mean, combinatorics is often a tool to write a good program, right? Just like an editor, no?

Comment: Why not ask this on the mathematics site? Fundamentally, this isn’t a programming problem, but a maths problem.

Comment: @user4642212 It would be off-topic on *math.se* too. College-level question, with no attempt to solve it.

Comment: "Just like an editor, no?" - and it just so happens that only a subset of questions about editors are actually going to be on-topic. So yes, you are probably very right that it is just like that.

Comment: @Gimby, I should have made the [sarcasm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401968/how-should-i-have-flagged-this-vim-centric-question) more evident.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, that is off-topic. That question is a math problem, not a programming one. Sure, at some moment in time it might be used in a program, but that is not what that question is about.

We do accept questions about editors if it is to solve an issue with programming For example: *How can I indent all lines?* (probably a Python dev) or *How can I find the next closing bracket?* (all other devs). If you ask *How do I save a file* or *How do I install edlin?* we happily divert you to [Super User](https://superuser.com/).